# Issue when using a custom font - "native typeface cannot be made"

Tags: java, android, listview, fonts, textview

I'm trying to use a font I found on the internet, but the problem is that I get an FC with "native typeface cannot be made".

Here is the code in the getView of my ListVIew:

```
        holder.tv_SuraName   =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Start_Name);
        holder.tv_SuraName.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "suralist_font.ttf"));
```

Can anyone tell me why can I use the custom rom? You can get it [HERE](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18331007/suralist_font.ttf) .. the file is .ttf

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The font file is either corrupt or unsupported for some reason. You can drop it on the SD card and load it from file, to make sure it's not a problem with your assets.

Comment: I just tried from File and now the font works! But this means I have a problem with my assets folder, will this affect anything else? Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't affect other stuff. You can try rebuilding your apk, but not sure what exactly is the problem. Maybe it fails to decompress the file? Try using the newest Android SDK.

Comment: how to drop it out on sdcard ? when a random person is downloading my app from the play store?

Comment: As a side note: Android studio users need to create an assests folder in src/main because of gradle build rather than the build/assets folder.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio/18302624#18302624

Answer (score 48):

My problem was incorrect placement of the assets folder.

When using Android Studio the assets folder should be inside of the source sets e.g.

> src/main/assets/

Found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302624/1819347)

Comment: This is the answer. Just saved my time. THanks!

Answer (score 29):

There are basically 4 things that can cause this:

1. You use the wrong extension
2. You have to place the fonts in the assets folder and **not** inside assets/fonts/
3. You misspelled the fonts
4. The fonts need to be lowercase (in my case the solution was to rename MyFont.ttf to myfont.ttf, strange)

Comment: In my case, I was using Bootstrap and the font needed to be copied at the **root of the assets folder**. Your answer helped figured it out so +1.

Comment: In my case the problem was lowercase

Comment: Mine was number two. Good point that might help a lot of people

Answer (score 21):

Double check the extension isn't in caps, ie. suralist_font.TTF

Fonts often come seem to come that way and it might be overlooked.

Comment: Just helped me out with that! :)

Comment: this solved the problem for me too, the bebas font file is something like BEBAS___.TFF -- thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

I had this same problem, I created mine in assets>fonts>whatever.ttf and was getting the same error.  I added the fonts extension (fonts/whatever.ttf) and it fixed the problem in every case.

```
 holder.tv_SuraName   =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Start_Name);
 holder.tv_SuraName.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),    "fonts/suralist_font.ttf"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather old thread, but I want to add one more reason this can happen: You have to set the content view before calling typeface. See example below

Does **not** work:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/whatever.ttf");
        title.setTypeface(font);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

**Does work!**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); // <-- call before typeface

        TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/whatever.ttf");
        title.setTypeface(font);
    }
```

Comment: `fonts/whatever.ttf` part saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am using android studio, in my case problem was with the path of assets folder, in Eclipse path for assets folder is **res/assets/** but in Android Studio its **src/main/assets/**
So, i just move my font file to this path and finally problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Either your font file is corrupt else you making some mistake in spelling while calling your file name. I had same issue, it was because file name specified in asset folder was

> roboto_black.ttf

and while declaring in java file, i have been spelling it as:

> roboto_blak.ttf

If your .ttf files are in asset folder,then use:

```
Typeface type_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "roboto_black.ttf");
```

Else if it is in fonts folder, then use:

```
type_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/roboto_black.ttf");
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare states in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3717615/19679)

> I would guess that there is a problem with the font itself. That error
>   will be triggered when native code in the OS attempts to load the
>   typeface.

Anyway try this one:

```
holder.tv_SuraName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Start_Name);
Typeface Font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"suralist_font.ttf");
holder.tv_SuraName.setTypeface(Font);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

Typeface.createFromAsset leaks asset stream: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with COMIC.TTF from comic sans ms of Windows.
Since the original file I placed in assets/fonts folder was in uppercase as spelt above, I had to type it exactly in uppercase.
     Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/COMIC.TTF");

it turns out the problem was caused by the lower case:
     Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/comic.ttf");

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this is due to either a corrupt file or you have placed the file in the wrong folder.

According to Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

> main/assets/
>   This is empty. You can use it to store raw asset files. Files that you save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the original filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of bytes using the AssetManager. For example, this is a good location for textures and game data.

Therefore your folder structure should be ***yourmodule/main/assets*** (e.g. a***pp/main/assets*** )

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was first changing my font name to only lower case and underscore: from **Amatic-Sc.ttf** to **amatic_sc.ttf**.

Then in the set.TypeFace method change **assets/fonts/amatic_sc.ttf** to just **fonts/amatic_sc.ttf**.

Answer (score 0):

I've been debugging forever on this error in Android Studio. Clean and rebuilding the project after adding the fonts to the assets directory fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a `build --> clean` and it started rendering .

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue which happened on Android 4.0.3-4.0.4 (100% reproducible on emulator IceCreamSandwich mips 4.0.3).

The problem was that TTF fonts, that I had, were not correct, despite almost all Android versions were able to load those TTF font. So I used https://cloudconvert.com/woff-to-ttf (since I had woff files as well) to make new TTF fonts, which solved my problem.