# Android using typeface

Tags: android

I am trying to use a custom font in my app but I am getting an error. My code is this:

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Oxigen_Regular.ttf");
     TextView texto_titulo =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ref_articulo);
     texto_titulo.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

I have the font in fonts folder inside assets folder. I don´t know what is happening, I am doing this in ActionBarActivity. It says: "native typeface cannot be made". Someone knows the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531856/issue-when-using-a-custom-font-native-typeface-cannot-be-made

Comment: you could try to rename the ttf file to `oxigen.ttf` without upper case

Comment: I have changed to oxigenregular.ttf but still not working

Answer (score 1):

your code is this:

```
"fonts/Oxigen_Regular.ttf"
```

which means, you **"must"** have your font file under *fonts* folder, with **case sensitive** letters, including the ttf extenstion.

if original font name is: Oxigen_Regular.TTF or oxigen_regular.ttf inside your fonts asset folder, your code Oxigen_Regular.ttf will give error. It needs to be **precisely** the same as that you write programmatically.

Comment: The original name now is oxigenregular.ttf and programmatically is oxigenregular.ttf, this is not the cause of the error but thanks

Comment: are you also sure that your font is under "assets/fonts" folder?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use any external font means you have to download and put it in assets folder in application.
use this link for download fonts

http://www.1001freefonts.com/

use this code

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can oxigen.ttf keep in assets/oxigen.ttf (should be small latter oxigen.ttf)

and then call

```
TextView texto_titulo =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ref_articulo);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "oxigen.ttf");
        texto_titulo.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
```

must be import

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
```

I am sure you solve 100%. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the font that I downloaded was corrupt... I have downloaded from a new repository and now works perfectly. Sorry.