# Native typeface cannot be made

Tags: android, fonts

I am trying to set custom font in Android Studio..I have kept .ttf font file inside src-main-assets-fonts folder and i am typing this code in activity-

```
 Typeface avenirdemifont ;
avenirdemifont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "avenirdemifont.ttf");

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            textView.setTypeface(avenirdemifont);
```

I am getting following error "native typeface cannot be made"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531856/issue-when-using-a-custom-font-native-typeface-cannot-be-made
check this, also check your font property

Comment: @RohanPawar already seen that

Comment: so check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to add "fonts" directory to path. Try this:

```
 Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/avenirdemifont.ttf");
```