# native typeface cannot be made for font

Tags: android, font-awesome, android-typeface

I have a rather traditional question. In my app I have this line:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
```

And it returns an exception:

```
RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
```

What I have:

- my `assets` folder is in `src/main/` folder of my app;
- In build.gradle file a wrote the following lines:

  `sourceSets {
      main {
          assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
      }
  }`
- my filename and extension are in lower case.

I wrote I think all the stackoverflow posts about this problem and tried the following solutions:

- I wrote `context.getAssets()` and `context.getRessources().getAssets()` instead of simply `getAssets()`
- I tried to put my font file to fonts dauther older and directly to assets folder
- I tried to check TTF extension instead of ttf
- I tried to remove - and _ simbols from the file name

Nothing has helped me. May be you know another solution?

Thank you.

Comment: where is your assets folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531856/issue-when-using-a-custom-font-native-typeface-cannot-be-made

Comment: dmxherazi, have you read my text? there is a line that describes the localization of my assets.

Comment: Oops Sorry! Try to rename the file as I mentioned in the answer

Comment: is the filename spelt correctly? i had a same issue wherein the name of the font file was different in code then the actual file name

Comment: vishnus, I used copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

<del>It seems that your assets folder might be misplaced. When using Android Studio the assets folder should be inside of the source sets e.g. `src/main/assets/`</del>

<del>Also rename the font and remove `-` with `_` and make appropriate changes in the code as well.</del>

**UPDATE**

I tried to reproduce your issue and found that the issue might be because of an invalid font file. Most probably the downloaded ttf is corrupt. Use [this file for fontawsome-webfont](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Juf5kLJb5QTGFEZzBOb0pjOGM/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: have you tried to rename the file and remove `-` character.

Comment: My file version can be opened very well. I don't think it's my case.