# Android application crashing on Typeface.createFromAsset

Tags: android

My application is crashing on the following code. I am trying to give a custom font in a textView. The asset directory is fine as I have double checked it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    String BANGLA_FONT_SOLEMAN_LIPI = "/SolaimanLipi_Bold_10-03-12.ttf";
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
            BANGLA_FONT_SOLEMAN_LIPI);
    title.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

When the application crashes it produces the following Error Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gsl.banglafonttest/com.gsl.banglafonttest.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:174)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5409)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
                                                                                at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
                                                                                at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
                                                                                at com.gsl.banglafonttest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2328)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:174) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5409) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where u kept the assets folder?

Comment: I hope you have seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531856/issue-when-using-a-custom-font-native-typeface-cannot-be-made

Comment: Setting typeface using java code is hard due to multiple lines, I have created a library to set custom fonts. You can find a library usage in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42001474/4446392

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically 4 things that can cause this:

1.You use the wrong extension

2.You placed the fonts in the assets folder and not inside assets/fonts/

3.You misspelled the fonts

4.The fonts need to be lowercase (in my case the solution was to rename MyFont.ttf to myfont.ttf, strange)

Comment: The problem in my case was number 2. I placed the fonts in assets/fonts folder and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/Nunito-Light.ttf");
                vh.textView_header.setTypeface(tf,45);

This is a sample i used in my application, the custom font is within the font folder in the android assets directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) to get rid of custom TextView or "boilerplate" .setTypeFace

I used to have custom TextView but Calligraphy made my code far cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I tried this and it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case is creating a font folder in assets folder and keeping the file there.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    String BANGLA_FONT_SOLEMAN_LIPI = "font/SolaimanLipi_22-02-2012.ttf";
    Context cn=getApplicationContext();
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(cn.getAssets(),
            BANGLA_FONT_SOLEMAN_LIPI);
    title.setTypeface(tf);
    title.setText(R.string.text_of_title);
}
```

}