# Why am i getting these errors, java truetype error?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, error-handling, barcode

Why does eclipse not let me compile this.
I want for myself to click on a button then the `Edittext` data goes to a `Textview`. then from there i want the `textView` to be converted to a bar-code by pressing another `Button`, so i have 2 `Buttons` and 2 `textViews` and 1 `editTexts` altogether

Please tell how to do this or where i,m wrong

```
public class cc extends Activity {

EditText inputc;
TextView outputc;
TextView tv1;
ImageView iv;
Button b;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.cc);

inputc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ccinput);
outputc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputc);
Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
final TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputc);  
tv1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 

//To change to code 39 barCode font
Typeface barcodefont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/IDAutomationHC39M_FREE.otf");         
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputc);         
tv.setTypeface(barcodefont);

send.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv1.buildDrawingCache(); 
        iv.setImageBitmap(tv1.getDrawingCache()); 
        outputc.setText((inputc.getText()));
    }
});

}
}
```

ADTIONAL INFO.
I have compiled but now I get error, here is logcat:

```
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.barcodedisplayer/com.example.barcodedisplayer.cc}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5303)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at com.example.barcodedisplayer.cc.onCreate(cc.java:32)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
10-16 15:41:11.095: E/AndroidRuntime(5822):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: If the compiler actually complains, please include the ***error messages*** and ***the lines on which you get the errors*** please.

Comment: The answer to this question would be better served as a lesson on how to use the compiler moreso then whatever specific problem the code has.

Comment: post the error messages , post your log cat

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid - If it doesn't compile, then it won't run; if it doesn't run there won't be any logcat

Comment: If it can't compile, then how do you have a logcat?

Comment: @NickT : what do you mean by it wont run , execute it , it would fail at some point , which will be visible in logcat

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid - if it ran, then it must have compiled successfully.

Comment: i have a logcat in the original post, please take a look

Comment: Without looking at all this code, I'd say it won't compile because it's not valid Java. To fix it, write valid Java. There are excellent books on the subject.

Comment: It actually does compile, there nothing wrong with the java, an issue with Assets is more likely

Comment: @xiHarpzZ if it compiles you need to update your question title which says cannot compile

Comment: Title was changed ages ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your logcat points to this line:

`Typeface barcodefont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/IDAutomationHC39M_FREE.otf");`

Make sure `fonts/IDAutomationHC39M_FREE.otf` exists, it is not corrupt, and that the name capitalization matches exactly.

Alternatively, if the above doesn't work, try the suggestions found here: [Custom fonts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3717054/751245)

Comment: Hi, im aware of this situation i have double and triple checked that the words and grammer are correct. however still i get the error

Comment: If possible, then try using a different font, like a TTF font since [TTF is apparently better supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426244/use-external-fonts-in-android). If you can get another font working, then we can rule out the font itself being the problem

Comment: I have used about 5 .TTF fonts none of which h=seem to work. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your ImageView `iv` is not initialized. You will get `NullPointerException`. Initialize iv

```
 iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourimageviewid);
```

This is one the error's. As @NickT pointed out this would be a run time error.

You have textview outputc and tv1 both initialized with the same id `R.id.outputc`

```
  outputc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputc); 
  final TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputc);
```

And you have

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(outputc); 
 // remove this line  or use R.id.yourtextviewid
 // outputc is a textview
```

Make sure you have `IDAutomationHC39M_FREE.otf` under /assests/fonts.

Comment: Won't cause the compile errors he's talking about but definitely is an issue for run-time when it finally does compile.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. i have corrected it now i have an error, logcat is in the OP

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo` is the error, stated in the logcat in the above question

Comment: @xiHarpzZ did you change this line `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputc)` ??

Comment: @meda has now fixed it however im getting a differnt error now. `10-16 15:31:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(3110): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.barcodedisplayer/com.example.barcodedisplayer.cc}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
`

Comment: @xiHarpzZ do you this `IDAutomationHC39M_FREE.otf` under /assests/fonts

Comment: Yes i do, i ahve also check others im also tried `IDAutomationSC128M.ttf` whcih has the same error

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here:

You already declared `TextView tv1;` so you don't have to do it again `final TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputc);`

You also mentionned:

> so i have 2 Buttons and 2 textViews and 1 editTexts altogther

public class cc extends Activity {

```
EditText inputc;
TextView outputc;
TextView tv1;
ImageView iv;
Button b;
Button send;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cc);

    inputc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ccinput);
    outputc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputc);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputc);
    tv1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    //To change to code 39 barCode font
    Typeface barcodefont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), 
                "fonts/IDAutomationHC39M_FREE.otf");


    outputc.setTypeface(barcodefont);

    send.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv1.buildDrawingCache();
            iv.setImageBitmap(tv1.getDrawingCache());
            outputc.setText((inputc.getText()));
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @meda. Much appreciated thanks. however now im facing another error `10-16 15:31:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(3110): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.barcodedisplayer/com.example.barcodedisplayer.cc}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made`