# How to use korean font in android

Tags: android

In my application I am using custom **korean** font "NanumGothic.ttf".

```
public void setFontTextView(Context c, TextView name) {
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),"fonts/NanumGothic.ttf");
name.setTypeface(font);
}
```

I have to show two language support english and korean.
application is not showing me that korean font and also changing the text alignment.
if i am using some other trueType font like arial.ttf etc instead of that they are working fine.

So is there any support to use korean font in android??

Comment: I think you should find a hand-writing Korean font and do it like above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Fonts in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203694/custom-fonts-in-android)