# Problem in how to integrate font for android Application

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, android-emulator, android-widget

I want to set the font for my application. The font is like "JOURNAL". 
But the problem is, i don't know how to integrate it in to myapplication. and if i integrate it then would it be for all the application or for only the selected application? because I want it to be set just for only one application. not for all.
So for that what should i have to do ? 
I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103777/how-to-use-korean-font-in-android). but i think it is for only TextView and not for whole application font.
So, Is there anything i have to do in manifest file ??? or what else i have to do ??
Please help me regarding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree to @Kheldar statement. There is no method to change the font in an Android app. Try this code to avoid calling a set method each time you want to change the font of an element.

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

Context context;
String ttfName;

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;

    for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
        this.ttfName = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.package.my", "ttf_name");

        init();
    }
}

private void init() {
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), ttfName);
    setTypeface(font);
}

@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf) {
    super.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:package="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.package.my"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <com.package.my.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        package:ttf_name="My-font.otf" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. But I have that font file in to my pc. named as "JOURNAL.ttf" Sowhere should i have to put that font file ??

Comment: Put it in the assets folder. name it with lower cases and change the xml file to match the file name.

Comment: suppose i have button in layout and on the button text i want to set this font then ?? Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Just change the model's extension from TextView to Button.

Comment: Ok. Thanks its works great. I have also find one example from here. http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/04/using-custom-fonts-on-android.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the fonts system-wide from an application (at least, as far as I know and barring some exploit).

Study this link: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/

Comment: Yes Thanks. Its realy a great tutorial to help others also.

Comment: There is little help i want. If i want to set the font in xml file then ? because in tutorial the demo is for to set the font in java file not in xml file.

Comment: what should i have to do if every time i dont want to use that two lines to set the font ???

Comment: You should look into theming then. Themes are precisely for this purpose!