# Setting Button text font in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-fonts

I have a `button` created using android widgets. I want to set the font of the button text to `Helv Neue 67 Med Cond`. How to get this font and set it to the button text in android layout file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First you have to put the ttf file in assets folder and then You can use the below code to set Custom font in TextView, same way you can do for Button:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Helv Neue 67 Med Cond.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 25):

I guess you may have already found the answer, but if not (and for other developers), you can do it like this:

1.you want to save the "Helv Neue 67 Med Cond.ttf" in to assets folder.
then

**For TextView**

```
  TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
  Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Helv Neue 67 Med Cond.ttf");
  txt.setTypeface(typeface);
```

**For Button**

```
  Button n=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Helv Neue 67 Med Cond.ttf");
  n.setText("show");
  n.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you plan to add the same font to several buttons I suggest that you go all the way and implement subclass button:

```
public class ButtonPlus extends Button {

    public ButtonPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public ButtonPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public ButtonPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
            Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface("fonts/candy.ttf", context);
            setTypeface(customFont);
        }
    }
```

And here's the FontCache to reduce memory usage on older devices:

```
public class FontCache {

    private static Hashtable<String, Typeface> fontCache = new Hashtable<>();

    public static Typeface getTypeface(String name, Context context) {
        Typeface tf = fontCache.get(name);
        if(tf == null) {
            try {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), name);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            fontCache.put(name, tf);
        }
        return tf;
    }
}
```

And finally an example use in a layout:

```
 <com.my.package.buttons.ButtonPlus
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_sometext"/>
```

This may seem like an awful lot of work, but you'll thank me once you have couple of handfuls of buttons and textfields that you want to change font on.

Also you can see this [tutorial](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/custom-fonts-in-android/#sthash.TplSUNFo.dpbs) and a example in [GitHub](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/CustomFonts).

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
android:typeface="yourfont"
```

Comment: Yes correct. But I want Helv Neue 67 Med Cond font. How can I get this font?

Comment: Not for custom fonts; extend each element or look into using a custom layout inflater.

Answer (score 2):

Android comes with 3 fonts `(Sans, Serif, Monospace)` which can be accesed using `android:typeface=”FONT_NAME”`.

For using custom font, you should use code like

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
  Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Helv Neue 67 Med Cond.ttf");
  txt.setTypeface(typeface);
```

---

Some similar questions are [Custom Fonts in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203694/custom-fonts-in-android) and [Android - Using Custom Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font).

Answer (score 0):

You have to download `Helv Neue 67 Med Cond` font and store it in assets folder. let the downloaded font is `myfont.ttf`

Use the following code to set the font

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfont.ttf");
        TextView TextViewWelcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewWelcome);
        TextViewWelcome.setTypeface(tf);
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

This is a good article, I used it several times and works:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/