# Applying custom fonts in buttons for android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, fonts

I am trying to add a custom roboto font to my android button; however, most solutions aren't working in this case.

I am trying to use solutions from here...[Setting Button text font in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372458/setting-button-text-font-in-android)

I have fonts right here in my assets folder.

[image]

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
  Button block_block_font =(Button) findViewById(R.id.block_button);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        block_block_font.setText("show");
        block_block_font.setTypeface(typeface);

        Button security_settings_button_font =(Button) findViewById(R.id.security_settings_button);
        security_settings_button_font.setText("show");
        security_settings_button_font.setTypeface(typeface);

        Button blacklist_whitelist_button_font  =(Button) findViewById(R.id.blacklist_whitelist_button);
        blacklist_whitelist_button_font.setText("show");
        blacklist_whitelist_button_font.setTypeface(typeface);
```

However, when I apply that solution for editing I produce this error:

```
06-14 16:59:56.677  26389-26389/com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app/com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
            at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:307)
            at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:281)
            at com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Not sure why a native typeface cannot be made for me when it works for everyone else ...?

Comment: There would appear to be a problem with the specific font file you are trying to use.

Comment: AFAIK creating your own folders in assets isn't supported by Android as of yet.

Comment: I don't know if that is the case because this is able to work with my textviews in another activity (the font that is)

Comment: Yes, on continuing to research, I am wrong. (Though that holds true for drawables.)

Comment: And, in researching found this [potential duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531856/issue-when-using-a-custom-font-native-typeface-cannot-be-made)

Comment: I am trying to find out if my assets folder is misplaced...?

Answer (score 2):

create an assets directory and put your customefont.ttf file inside that directory..

```
    Button bu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.custom_font); 
    Typeface    font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"yourCustomeFont.ttf"); 
    bu.setTypeface(font);
```

This way worked for specific button But what if u want to apply this font for the entire app u can use this way apply this lib compile it in your gradle file `complie'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'`

After that 2 steps remain.

1- instantiate calligrapher and set the font onCreate method in the main activity

```
  Calligrapher calligrapher = new Calligrapher(this);       
  calligrapher.setFont(this, "yourCustomFontHere.ttf", true);
```

And if you want to make this font accessed by the whole app so instead of step 1 do this instantiate the Calligraphy in the Class that extends the application class like that :

```
  CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/yourCustomFontHere.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build()
    );
```

2- inject it into the context, by overriding attachBaseContext method in the main Activity like that:

```
  @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

This is the most elegant super fast way to do that ..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, it looks like your assets folder is in your src folder.

Move assets up to the project root and give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your fonts in the assets folder directly and change to reference the asset name without folder name at the start, then try.

**Or**
Remove the assets folder in src and put it app/main directly.