# Using font in XML in API < 26

Tags: android, fonts

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html

Android API 26 supports this but do we have a support library that can provide use of fonts as a resource in res? [ font in XML ] If yes, up-to what API is it supported?

I am talking about the Android O SDK feature which allows us to set font in XML as given in the link above.  This is not a native feature in MM I m sure.

Comment: I'm using this feature in one of my apps, which supports API 9 to API 18. There's no limitation as far as I know. I stopped supporting API 8, but I guess it would have worked with it as well.

Comment: Which library you have added to gradle?

Comment: NONE. It's a native feature. By the way, Eclipse doesn't need all that "Gradle thing" ;)

Comment: I think I m being misunderstood. I m talking about "font in XML" feature that was introduced in O. Edited question to clarify

Comment: You can do the very same in previous versions. With some little trick you can easily find by googling.

Comment: Setting @font/resource_name doesnt work with support library version 25.3.1 on Android Studio 2.3.2. Font in XML is clearly **NOT A NATIVE FEATURE**

Comment: In facts, I said `With some little trick`. I use custom fonts in my `raw/fonts` folder. See this for your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9035924/2649012

Comment: `with some little trick` != a native feature

Comment: Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to Google it is supported on **Android 4.0+ (API 14+)** as long as these conditions are met:

- You are using the **support library** version **26.0.0-beta1** or later
- You are using **AppCompat**

Sources:

[Fonts in XML - Using the support library](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/fonts-in-xml.html#using-support-lib)

[Support Library revision history](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0-beta1)

I was hoping I could use this in app widgets on Android versions earlier than 8 (API 26), however it's not possible, as AppCompatTextView cannot be used in app widgets. None of the third party alternatives to Android O's 'Fonts in XML' such as the [Caligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library work in app widgets either.

The only alternative for app widgets is using an **ImageView** instead of a **TextView** and using **RemoteViews** methods such as **setImageViewUri(...)** and **setImageViewBitmap(...)**, both of which are problematic.

Comment: Thanks. Why were others saying that its a native feature? I m using SDK Android Studio 2.3.2. I tried using @font/arial.ttf. It didnt work. I was using support library version 25.3.1. Now I know what was wrong.

Comment: did this work? some people are saying you must upgrade to Android Studio 3 for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I changed my <TextView> to <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView> and it works now.

Answer (score 69):

To support font family on `API` lower than 26, we need to use

```
<font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/myfont-Regular"/>
```

instead of

```
<font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="400" android:font="@font/myfont-Regular"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: As stated in the docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml#using-support-lib

Answer (score 29):

To complete Yuri's answer, Fonts are supported back to API 16.
To create font family (where different weights of fonts are specified), you should create `my_font_family.xml` under **/res/font/** as written [in the doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml):

```
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/myfont_regular"/>
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="600" app:font="@font/myfont_semi_bold" />
    <font app:fontStyle="italic" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/myfont_italic" />
</font-family>
```

To use this in `TextView` xml, you should use `app:fontFamily="@font/my_font_family"`, be careful with `app:` instead of `android:`.

To choose specific `fontWeight`, you can use `android:textFontWeight="200"` but it only works on API>=28. To choose different font based on weight prior to API 28, you have two options. You can either use  `android:textStyle="bold"` to specify only "normal/italic/bold", but not exact weight. Or you can directly use specific weight of font like this:  `app:fontFamily="@font/myfont_semi_bold"`.

**Please Note**: If you are using custom textview, `YourTextView`, in your app, it has to extend `AppCompatTextView` and not merely `android.widget.TextView`

Comment: Did you try `textFontWeight`? Because even on API 28 it doesn't work for me.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I am running in an emulator . I am using  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' and MaterialComponents theme

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala Please check the note added, that might help you.

Comment: textStyle solution doesn't work on Android 5 with support library

Answer (score 7):

Some users will land up to this page searching for instructions to use custom fonts in your app from xml. Here's how I did it:

The font resource directory is not present by default. You can create it manually by following the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html) [too much work]

**Or use font selector from GUI-**

- Select a TextView in Design tab.
- Open drop down of `fontFamily` xml attribute.
- Scroll down to "More Fonts".
- Choose a 'Downloadable font" from the pop up that appears.

Android Studio will automatically create font resource directory with necessary declarations mentioned in documentation above. After this step you can copy your custom font file (say myfont.ttf) in font directory and set your desired font from xml for example:

```
<TextView
     android:fontFamily="@font/myfont"
     android:id="@+id/aboutus_head_textview"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/who_are_we" />
```

If you want to use the same font throughout your app, you can set fontFamily your AppTheme in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <!-- custom font for the entire app -->
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/myfont</item>
    </style>
```

[ prefix fontFamily with `android:` if above did not work ]

Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Note: This answer assumes you are using Android Studio 3+ and support library version 26+**

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, min sdk support 18 (in app)

https://github.com/mukundrd/androidFonts

Comment: Is it posible to include older APIs?

Comment: I suppose, it's a simple project for API >= 26.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an undesired way of doing it, but if you have a global font (typeface) in xml, you could just create a Textview and get the typeface from there

```
TextView dummy = new TextView(context);
doSomethingWithTheTypeface(dummy.getTypeface());
```