# Applying custom font using font.xml in style ,support library 26.0.1

Tags: android, xml, android-fonts

I am trying to use fontFamily introduced in API 26 in style.

```
<style name="customfontstyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/LDFComicSans.ttf</item>
</style>
```

The documentation says:

> Using the support library
>
> The Support Library 26.0 provides support to the Fonts in XML feature on devices running Android API version 14 and higher.

If I use android prefix, It says fontFamily requires min API level 16.

```
<style name="customfontstyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/LDFComicSans.ttf</item>
</style>
```

I can't apply font using style with support lib when i use "fontFamily".

Support lib version: **26.0.1**

Comment: Support library for what? There is no "support library" in XML, please add tags to explain what you are trying to do and on what platform

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I've updated the questions and tags

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505878/using-font-in-xml-in-api-26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style name="PrimaryFontTheme" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#898282</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
</style>
```

> I just applied attribute "android:fontFamily" and Its working well :)
>   Problem Solved