# Can't use fonts in my project: - "Error:Error: The file name must end with .xml"

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-debug, android-fonts

I'm trying to add a font to my Android project, so I can use it via XML. 
Unfortunately, I'm getting this error message:

> Error:Error: The file name must end with .xml

I followed every step of the official Android tutorial and somehow this error occurs and I can't fix it.

[image: Here is this my error]

Comment: Did you solve this problem or reverted back to old 'assets' folder solution?

Comment: Ok, I'm done by fully updating the AndroidStudio and Gradle plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You can't add `font.ttf` file in `Drawable`  folder

you need to create **Assets folder** in android 
you can create Assets folder like below image in Android studio

[image]

than create a font folder in Assets folder and put your custom **font.ttf** file in this folder like below image

[image]

Comment: "Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces a new feature, Fonts in XML, which lets you use fonts as resources. You can add the font file in the res/font/" ?

Comment: @7Learner you didn't mention in question about api level 26 please read this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html#using-support-lib

Comment: @7Learner  check this link it may help you https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html#using-supporthttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505878/using-font-in-xml-in-api-26-lib and this

Comment: man!! if you create the assets directory like--  res ->right click -> new -> Directory- >  name it "assets". Then if you put any file in that assets folder you wont be able to read that file with asset manager. took me 3 hours to realise this thing. Always create it like res ->right click -> new -> Folder -> Assets Folder

Answer (score 0):

Put the font in your project in assets/fonts directory

then in your code to get the Typeface:

```
Typeface myNewTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/the_new_font.ttf");
```

Comment: "Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces a new feature, Fonts in XML, which lets you use fonts as resources. You can add the font file in the res/font/" ?

Comment: I did not test this new feature. My applications must also work in earlier versions of Android and therefore I can not use that.