# Custom Fonts with Support Library is not working on a real device

Tags: android, font-family

I have used custom font with Support Library API 26. I have created font-family using style and add style to my text view. I found that font is going to set in Preview during design, but not working in android real devices. Below is my code and I have also attached screenshot. Thanks in advance.

**TextView:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/card_number_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="111 5235 5563 8845"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    style="@style/creditCardText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/payableLayout"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/payableLayout"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />
```

**Style.xml:**

```
<style name="creditCardText">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSizeLarge</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_roboto_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_card_number</item>
</style>
```

**Font Family:**

```
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/roboto_medium" />
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
    repositories {
    }
    dependencies {
   }
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
   compileSdkVersion 26
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.saifintex.skypaytrans"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 7
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
   }

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false        // true by default
    checkAllWarnings false
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    ignoreWarnings true       // false by default
    quiet true                // false by default
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
productFlavors {
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/fonts']
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
compile "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"
compile project(':tooltip')
compile project(':mylibrary')
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile "com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-
android:${rootProject.ormliteAndroidVersion}"
compile "com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:${rootProject.ormliteCoreVersion}"
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.2'
compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
compile 'com.github.ayalma:ExpandableRecyclerView:0.2.0'
compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'
compile 'com.alimuzaffar.lib:pinentryedittext:1.3.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex") && 
        !requested.name.startsWith("crash")) {
            details.useVersion '25.3.1'
        }
    }
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Font resource dir:**

[image]

**Design preview:** Here font is working

[image]

**Android Device Screenshot:** Here font is not working

[image]

Comment: did you apply the style to your textview? Check the xml

Comment: I see the same problem. I tried referencing the font directly (instead of via a font-family), and also tried both otf and ttf files. It works in Android Studio preview, but not on an API 24 device.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Yogesh  did you find any solution

Comment: @Yogesh any soloution??

Answer (score 47):

Change your TextView to an android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45208134/332798

Comment: I've spent the last 8 hours trying to work out why some of my views were using my font and some weren't. Your answer lead me to the explanation - the description of AppCompatTextView specifically says "You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views." and that's exactly what I'm doing! Thanks so much for saving my sanity!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This also worked for me. In my case I was creating programmatically CheckedTextView and the default font wasn't working, changing to AppCompatCheckedTextView did the trick! :)

Comment: Weird thing is that I need AppCompat even for Android 7.1.1. I'm not sure if it's related to AndroidX, I have already my project to it.
Anyways, it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I spent hours trying to figure out why the font wasn't working. I was trying to migrate from Calligraphy library and you have to disable the default font setup in Application class.

```java
setDefaultFontPath(app.getString(R.string.font_path_medium))
```

Replace the default font setup with this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">your_front</item>
</style>

<style name="RobotoButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">your_font</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Requirement

- 1) assets folder which has sub folder "/fonts"
- 2) require custom fonts ".ttf" files in /fonts folder.
- 3) enum
- 4) attrs.xml file
- 5) java class
- 6) Usage

---

1)
create assets folder in

```
src/main/assets
```

---

2)
add custom fonts in

```
src/main/assets/fonts/
```

---

3) enum

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;


@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public enum Fonts {

OpenSans_Bold("OpenSans-Bold.ttf", 0),
OpenSans_BoldItalic("OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf", 1),
OpenSans_CondBold("OpenSans-CondBold.ttf", 2),
OpenSans_CondLight("OpenSans-CondLight.ttf", 3),
OpenSans_CondLightItalic("OpenSans-CondLightItalic.ttf", 4),
OpenSans_ExtraBold("OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf", 5),
OpenSans_ExtraBoldItalic("OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf", 6),
OpenSans_Italic("OpenSans-Italic.ttf", 7),
OpenSans_Light("OpenSans-Light.ttf", 8),
OpenSans_LightItalic("OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf", 9),
OpenSans_Regular("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 10),
OpenSans_Semibold("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", 11),
OpenSans_SemiboldItalic("OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ttf", 12),

AudioWide_Regular("Audiowide_Regular.ttf", 13);

String stringValue;
int value;
Context context;

Fonts(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

Fonts(String toString, int value) {
    stringValue = toString;
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "fonts/" + stringValue;
}

}
```

---

4)
attrs.xml file

create attrs.xml in res/values folder

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="FontTextView">

    <attr name="customFont" format="enum">
        <enum name="OpenSans_Bold" value="0" />
        <enum name="OpenSans_BoldItalic" value="1" />
        <enum name="OpenSans_CondBold" value="2" />
        <enum name="OpenSans_CondLight" value="3" />
        <enum name="OpenSans_CondLightItalic" value="4" />
        <enum name="OpenSans_ExtraBold" value="5" />
        <enum name="OpenSans_ExtraBoldItalic" value="6" />
        <enum name="OpenSans_Italic" value="7" />
        <enum name="OpenSans_Light" value="8" />
        <enum name="OpenSans_LightItalic" value="9" />
        <enum name="OpenSans_Regular" value="10" />
        <enum name="OpenSans_Semibold" value="11" />
        <enum name="OpenSans_SemiboldItalic" value="12" />
        <enum name="Audiowide_Regular" value="13" />

    </attr>

</declare-styleable>
```

---

5)
FontTextView.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.Fonts;
import com.example.R;

@SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView")
public class FontTextView extends TextView {

public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public FontTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FontTextView, 0, 0);

    String fontText = a.getString(R.styleable.FontTextView_customFont);

    if (fontText != null) {
        switch (fontText) {
            case "0":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_Bold.toString();
                break;
            case "1":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_BoldItalic.toString();
                break;
            case "2":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_CondBold.toString();
                break;
            case "3":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_CondLight.toString();
                break;
            case "4":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_CondLightItalic.toString();
                break;
            case "5":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_ExtraBold.toString();
                break;
            case "6":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_ExtraBoldItalic.toString();
                break;
            case "7":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_Italic.toString();
                break;
            case "8":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_Light.toString();
                break;
            case "9":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_LightItalic.toString();
                break;
            case "10":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_Regular.toString();
                break;
            case "11":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_Semibold.toString();
                break;
            case "13":
                fontText = Fonts.AudioWide_Regular.toString();
                break;
            case "12":
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_SemiboldItalic.toString();
                break;
            default:
                fontText = Fonts.OpenSans_Regular.toString();
                break;
        }

        Log.e("String", fontText);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), fontText);

        setTypeface(tf);
    }
    a.recycle();
}

}
```

---

6)
Usage

```
    <com.example.FontTextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:text="this is custom font"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:customFont="OpenSans_Semibold" />
```

add below namespace to the top parents Layout of xml file
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

reference by :

```
"Android Custom TypeFace fontFamily "
```

[click here](http://dhiren-khatik.blogspot.in/2017/05/android-custom-typeface-fontfamily.html)

with this, you can easily add any font in android.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But I want to implement custom font as per Android O standard using support Design-
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Comment: @YogeshSrivastava thanks, but for this, I've not used this O feature yet. but I'll soon.

Answer (score 3):

Based on a similar issue I had, while also using the support library, I noticed this in the documentation:

> Note: When you declare font families in XML layout through the support library, use the app namespace to ensure your fonts load.

So I had a look and updated the fontFamily attribute to use app: instead of android, so in your case:

```
<item name="app:fontFamily">@font/font_roboto_medium</item>
```

instead of:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_roboto_medium</item>
```

Hope that helps! Seems to be a weird implementation of the support library causing the confusion here.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml#using-support-lib

Comment: This was the case for me. Thank you!

Comment: It didn't work for me. Android Studio gave me an error `Cannot resolve symbol 'app:fontFamily'`. And if I just ignore the error and build anyway, I get a build error `AAPT: error: style attribute 'app:attr/fontFamily' not found`. Is there some kind of namespace declaration I need to add to my `styles.xml` to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but I've encountered an issue with using fontFamily in FragmentActivities. In those activities the font is not correctly shown. If you let your activity extend from AppCompatActivity (which extends FragmentActivity) than the font is correctly shown.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using butterknife view injection for binding your custom text or button view, you should override `onFinishInflate()` method in custom view class.
For example:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    Typeface font_type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontStyle);
    this.setTypeface(font_type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `android support lib`  below `api 26` you can use this:

> create class **TypefaceUtil.java** and add code below

```
public class TypefaceUtil {
    public static void overrideFont(Context context, String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) {
        try {
            final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);

            final Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

... and in your application class that extends `Application class` add this:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SERIF", "fonts/myfont.ttf");
    }
```

... android add this class to manifest.xml

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

... and at the end add this line in you style:

```
<item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
```

but this is not working with support library api 26 and higher 
for this you can use this version

1. create a folder named font in res folder
2. put your font in this folder
3. create and xml file(font resource file)(myfont.xml) and add this code:

   ```
   <font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="400" android:font="@font/font"
       app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/font"/>

   <font android:fontStyle="italic" android:fontWeight="400" android:font="@font/font"
       app:fontStyle="italic" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/font" />
   ```

... and now add this line in the style code of your app:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/myfont</item>
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: oh, that simple! :-)

Comment: your answer is not related to support library! see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml#using-support-lib