# how to get font folder in xml or java

Tags: android, styles, assets, calligraphy

hi i want set font but i have a problem
i use calligraphy library for changing font

```
 new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/IRANSansMobile.ttf")
                                .build()))
```

but this get font from Assets folder!
now i want change bottom navigation font but now i cant access Assets folder!

```
<style name="Widget.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="fontFamily">@myfont/iransansmobile</item>
    </style>
```

so this is my question:
1.how can i set font in setDefaultFontPath from res/myfont folder?
2.how can i set font in  from Assets folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello i found this solution from [How to use custom font in android xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030204/how-to-use-custom-font-in-android-xml)

```
package com.vins.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                                               "your_font.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<com.vins.test.MyTextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="This is a text view with the font u had set in MyTextView class "
    android:textSize="30dip"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
   >
```

Good luck.