# rich UI toolkits, does this application use custom drawing table techniques or it is standard table [android]

Tags: android

I am new to Android Open Source Platform programming and recently created an application that displays flights information of Khujand International Airport. It uses http request to get XML data from the server and displays it on a List.

I'd like to ask you about the look and feel of one application that is on Google play, has a nice rich UI look. You may reach this app on Google play in the following URL
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.cybertek.airport.timetable
or here http://flights-info.ru/
and also screenshot is here
[image]

So my questions are:

- Is that application uses Canvas to draw flight in a table?
- Which fonts they have used?
- Is it possible to create this flight table using standard components like table?
- Do I need to learn Android Graphics programming to create such application???

My application looks like this
[image]

Also, I'd like to know if there any rich UI frameworks, toolkits for the Android that ease application development process???
Links resources are welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your questions:

*Is that application uses Canvas to draw flight in a table?*
That can be only answered by authors (maybe reverse engineering could answer this but I am not sure).

*Which fonts they have used?*
That looks like custom font.  You are probably better asking that question on a site dedicated to designers or use font recognition such as [this one](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). To use custom fonts on Android checkout following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203719/200272

*Is it possible to create this flight table using standard components like table?*
I think it could be done.

*Do I need to learn Android Graphics programming to create such application???*
If by graphics you mean "OpenGL" then I would say no. There is no need to use OpenGL.

*Also, I'd like to know if there any rich UI frameworks, toolkits for the Android that ease application development process???*
You can find several custom controls [here](https://github.com/commonsguy).  If you would like to develop mobile web applications there are number of frameworks (Jquery mobile, Sencha, PhoneGap, etc).