# How to use custom fonts in an android application?

Tags: android, user-interface, fonts

I would like to use new custom fonts in an android application. please be precise and specific when explaining, i am a newbie. Namely, i would like to let my android application use these new android custom fonts http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html. Thank you. please help.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3203694/1050058). To who answered, You guys should flag duplicate to encourage newbie search before ask. There are many similar questions on SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7197867/1436931

Comment: This should've been closed as a dupe, not as "not a real question"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can use custom fonts using this way,

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Refer this [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/) for Full knowledge.

Comment: anyway other way to do it in the layout xml files other than code?

Comment: i dont think we can do it using xml layout and the easy way to do it is from coding

Comment: thanks Aerrow,Sharath and Anup

Comment: @ejobity: Refer this too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to put the fonts .ttf file in your assets folder and assign it to a text field or anything you want to apply it to in your main activity like this:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Here's a great tutorial that will teach you all you need to know about this:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/

Answer (score 0):

try this links [here](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/localization-using-ttf-files.html) and [here](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/localization.html)

The .ttf files are used to get different format into our android application.
Its a easy way to work with .ttf files. The only thing you need to get is get all the available .ttf files by googling