# setting a custom font for a finished app

Tags: android, fonts

I have made an android app.after I finished the customer wants me to set a custom font for the entire app. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.You will have to add all fonts in assest folder.
Here is the example how to use -: [How to use custom fonts in an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756464/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-an-android-application)