# How to display letters with bottom dots in Android text view?

Tags: android, unicode, fonts, textview

As fas as I know, there is a big trouble with Indian fonts (like Devanagari) in Android. So I think of using [IAST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration) to avoid using Devanagari. But there are some letters with bottom dots (like ṃ or ḥ). They are unicode, I guess, because every text editor shows them easily. But my text view doesn't. What should I do?

**Update:** The solution is to use DejaVu fonts or any other set of fonts with full UNICODE support.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use custom fonts, since normal Android fonts do not support devanagari or m with dot below. See e.g. [Custom Fonts in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203694/custom-fonts-in-android/3203724#3203724).

Note that no font supports all of Unicode. You need to select one that supports the characters you need.

Comment: Devanagari font is not enough to use Devanagari in app - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4153

Also, DejaVuSans seems to be full featured (not sure, but this one worked for me).