# Where Can I Download Helvetica Neue Ultralight.ttf

Tags: android, text, fonts, textview

I want to know where I can download Helvetica Neue Ultralight.ttf for Android App.

I also want to know how to implement it in project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple Google search yielded a [download](http://what-font.co.uk/font-75789-helvetica_neue_ultralight.html) for the font, and a quick SO search yielded your [answer to add it to your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203694/custom-fonts-in-android).

Regards,
Nate

Comment: ThankU very much Nate. This is helpful :)

Comment: Link seems to be password protected now. I found them [here](http://64.92.105.155/fonts/helveticaNeue/)

Comment: It seems that @tagy22's link was deprecated. You need to buy that font. http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/neue-helvetica/25-ultra-light

Answer (score 0):

Use in class like this:

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                          "fonts/Verdana.ttf");

    tv.setTypeface(face);
```

put the font file in the fonts folder in /res/

Like my answer if it is helpful...