# Can one specify the fontType in android styles xml?

Tags: android, styles, font-face

I am following an example project "Sky" by Jeff Sharkey using styles in my layout.  It is working out quite well, however, I cannot determine how to specify the font type-face using the styles.  Without this, I will have to apply the font explicitly to every TextView, EditView, etc., whereas I want to control where and when it is applied throughout my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible from xml/styles... You can only specify it from java code.
[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android) if you are interesting.

Comment: That was my conclusion after some dialog with my colleagues -- but I was hoping for a clean solution without modifying the kernel :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating your own textview class and use that in your layouts.

Inside your new custom class, set the font you want.

Et voila!