# HTML tags not working within strings.xml

Tags: java, android, html, xml

I was trying to make bold text within my strings.xml using the HTML tag <b> and </b> as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019001/how-do-you-underline-a-text-in-android-xml):

```
<string name="name"><b>bold text here</b></string>
```

And then trying to set the text as follows:

```
TextView textview = new TextView(getActivity());
textview.setText(getString(R.string.name));
```

However this is not working at all, the tags are ignored and the text is displayed regularly. I have been able to make the text bold using the following method:

```
<string name="name">&lt;b>bold text here&lt;/b></string>
```

And with this code in Java:

```
TextView textview = new TextView(getActivity());
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.name)));
```

Why will the simple HTML tags not work yet this other method works just fine?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [`getText(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getText%28int%29) instead of [`getString(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29).

> Why will the simple HTML tags not work yet this other method works just fine?

Because the `getString(int)` method will return a string, that is stripped of styled text information, like the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString%28int%29) say.

As per the Android developer [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) the `getText(int)` method does not:

> `getText(int)` will retain any rich text styling applied to the string.

The `<string name="name">&lt;b>bold text here&lt;/b></string>` solution with `getString()` works because you've encoded the less than sign.

Comment: This doesn't work when you need to pass variables to strings.xml