# TextView selectable in code

Tags: android, textview

I can **select and highlight** some words in TextView (when it selectable) with long press on word, but I want to make it without touch.

So how can I select and highlight text in code itself or programattically ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the link effect you can put the `<u></u>` on your text in the `strings.xml` file.

Check this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019093/3465623

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it in your code by using [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

Here is the answer of your question.

```
    SpannableString ss1 = new SpannableString(s);
    ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.1f), 0, 6, 0); // set size and give character posiotion which you want to higlight
    ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 6, 0); // Color of highlighting your code.
    textview.setText(ss1);
```

Take a look at this [link](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html) which will shows you more use of **SpannableString**.