# How to underline the text from a string?

Tags: android, html, spannablestring

SpannableString and html tags wont work with the latest version of android studio. This is my first time in android studio. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you underline a text in Android XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019001/how-do-you-underline-a-text-in-android-xml)

Comment: [Underline A TextView in Android - XML & Java, Kotlin](https://androidride.com/underline-a-textview-in-android/)

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to achieve underlined text in TextView

```
   1- textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

   2- SpannableString strText = new SpannableString("Your Text here");
        strText.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(),6 , 11, 0);
        textView.setText(strText);

   3- in xml <u> Link Text</u>
```