# Display Japanese-style Chinese letters instead of Chinese-style Chinese letters when the system language is English

Tags: android, cjk

My question is similar to this ([Displaying japanese instead of chinese in a textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409015/displaying-japanese-instead-of-chinese-in-a-textview)), but a little bit different. The proposed solution is embedding a Japanese font in the app.

But I would not like to embed a Japanese font in the app, because it will increase the app size and I would have to buy an expensive font licence. It seems the Android emulator (Android 8.1) already has a Japanese font. How to use it, instead of embedding a font?

I mean, when I changed the system language to Japanese, it was like this:
[image]

But when the system language is English, it was like this (notice the third and fourth letters):
[image]

In case if you are wondering why I want to display them in Japanese style, I want to make a Japanese learning app, so it must display Japanese-style Chinese letters no matter what the system language is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since API 17 you can use [TextView.setTextLocale](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextLocale(java.util.Locale))

```
kanji.setTextLocale(Locale.JAPAN);
```