# How to specify Japanese encoding for a Label?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I attempt to display kanji a Label on Android, it gets displayed as Chinese instead of Japanese

For example, the difference between the character "直" in Chinese and Japanese:

[image: Chinese vs Japanese]

*(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification#Examples_of_language_dependent_characters) for more examples)*

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411812/238419), Android chooses the default based on whether or not the user has Japanese installed as a language.

Is there any way to tell it to pick the Japanese encoding?

Comment: Maybe you can add the custom font(display japanese test) to your Xamarin.Forms shared project as an embedded resource, register the font file with the assembly, you can take a look:[Set the font family](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#set-the-font-family)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution involving a custom renderer:

Android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(JapaneseLabelRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.Controls
{
    public class JapaneseLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        public JapaneseLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.TextLocale = Locale.Japan;
        }
    }
}
```