# How to specify Japanese encoding for a UILabel?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uilabel

When I attempt to display a Japanese string in a UILabel on iOS, it gets displayed using Chinese encoding instead of Japanese.

The two encodings are *nearly* identical, except in a few specific cases.  For example, here is how the character 直 (Unicode U+76F4) is rendered in Chinese (top) vs. Japanese (bottom):

[image: Chinese vs Japanese]

*(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification#Examples_of_language_dependent_characters) for more examples)*

The only time Japanese strings render correctly is when the user's system locale is `ja-jp` (Japan), but I'd like it to render as Japanese for *all* users.

**Is there any way to force the Japanese encoding?**  Android has `TextView.TextLocale`, but I don't see anything similar on iOS `UILabel`

*([Same question for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67797257/how-to-specify-japanese-encoding-for-a-label). I tagged this  Swift/Objective-C because, although I'm looking for a Xamarin.iOS solution, the API is almost the same)*

Comment: there are numerous existing questions on this topic - have you tried searching?  https://www.google.com/search?q=uilabel+display+japanese+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jason: Yes, I've read the first 50 or so of those results.  None of them are about Japanese vs Chinese encoding. The _only_ place I've seen this talked about is [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/61623), but no solution was found.

Comment: Please post the relevant code that you are using to display the label.  And what is the locale of the device set to?

Comment: @Jason Neither of those things should be relevant.  But: in Xamarin.Forms, it would be `<Label Text="直"/>` which gets translated to Xamarin.iOS `new UILabel { Text = "直" }` which gets translated to whatever the equivalent in Swift is.  The expected user locale is `en-US` or similar, because this is a Japanese learning app.  As mentioned, the unicode text is displayed _almost_ correctly, except that it uses Chinese encoding rather than Japanese encoding.

Comment: I tried the [approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22061784/8187800) the first one is not working ,  I think you have to take the second one , refer to [Xamarin.iOS solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/).

Comment: Just add support of japanese localization. for japanese users system will display right symbol

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT The second approach (and second link) are about localizing strings, which is completely unrelated to what I'm asking. See update, I tried to make the question more clear.

Comment: i think set your app's font by swift code is simplest way. `UILabel.appearance().font = .custom("Hiragino Sans", size: 30)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an *extremely* hacky solution that seems to work.  However, it seems absurd that there's no way to simply set the locale of a label, so if anyone finds something I missed, please post an answer.

---

The trick relies on the fact that the `Hiragino` font displays kanji using Japanese encoding rather than Chinese encoding by default.  However, the font looks like shit for English text, so I have to search every string in every label for Japanese substrings and manually change the font using `NSMutableAttributedString`. The font is also [completely broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44397572/238419) so I had to find another workaround to fix that.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(RingotanLabelRenderer))]
namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        private readonly UIFont HIRAGINO_FONT = UIFont.FromName("HiraginoSans-W6", 1); // Size gets updated later

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            // BUGFIX: Chinese encoding is shown by default. Switch to Hiragino font, which correctly shows Japanese characters
            // Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71045204/238419
            if (Control?.Text != null && e.PropertyName == "Text")
            {
                var kanjiRanges = GetJapaneseRanges(Control.Text).ToList();
                if (kanjiRanges.Count > 0)
                {
                    var font = HIRAGINO_FONT.WithSize((nfloat)Element.FontSize);
                    var attributedString = Control.AttributedText == null
                        ? new NSMutableAttributedString(Control.Text)
                        : new NSMutableAttributedString(Control.AttributedText);

                    // Search through string for all instances of Japanese characters and update the font
                    foreach (var (start, end) in kanjiRanges)
                    {
                        int length = end - start + 1;
                        var range = new NSRange(start, length);
                        attributedString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.Font, font, range);

                        // Bugfix: Hiragino font is broken (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44397572/238419) so needs to be adjusted upwards
                        // jesus christ Apple
                        attributedString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.BaselineOffset, (NSNumber)(Element.FontSize/10), range);
                    }

                    Control.AttributedText = attributedString;
                }
            }
        }

        // Returns all (start,end) ranges in the string which contain only Japanese strings
        private IEnumerable<(int,int)> GetJapaneseRanges(string str)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                if (IsJapanese(str[i]))
                {
                    int start = i;
                    while (i < str.Length - 1 && KanjiHelper.IsJapanese(str[i]))
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                    int end = i;
                    yield return (start, end);
                }
            }
        }

        private static bool IsJapanese(char character)
        {
            // An approximation. See https://github.com/caguiclajmg/WanaKanaSharp/blob/792f45a27d6e543d1b484d6825a9f22a803027fd/WanaKanaSharp/CharacterConstants.cs#L110-L118
            // for a more accurate version
            return character >= '\u3000' && character <= '\u9FFF' 
                || character >= '\uFF00';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to specify language identifier for attributed string, like

```
let label = UILabel()
let text = NSAttributedString(string: "直", attributes: [
    .languageIdentifier: "ja",                            // << this !! 
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 64)
])
label.attributedText = text
```

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

Comment: Unfortunately that attribute only seems to exist in iOS 15+. But at some point in the future this will be the better solution.  Thank you!