# Android – custom fonts crash app

Tags: android, fonts, crash

I'm trying to change font of a TextView to a custom one. Have read [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694163/custom-font-on-android) and tried instructions [as outlined here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/). The font in question is Roboto Thin, downloaded straight from [Android Design](https://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html) and is in **ttf**.

The code at the **main activity class** is as follows:

```
TextView txt  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hometext);                  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Thin.ttf");       
txt.setTypeface(font);

// "hometext" is the TextView I wish to change font of.
```

App does not crash when the above 3 lines are commented, which I hope isolates the problem.

Other etc info:

- Android 4.1.2 (API 16)
- testing on Android 4.4

#### EDIT:

Also tried "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf" and "assets/fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf", both don't work.

```
01-17 22:38:29.086: D/AndroidRuntime(17774): Shutting down VM
01-17 22:38:29.086: W/dalvikvm(17774): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415f4ba8)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774): Process: sp.com, PID: 17774
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sp.com/sp.com.POSServices}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at sp.com.POSServices.onCreate(POSServices.java:18)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-17 22:38:29.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17774):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you post your stacktrace/logcat?

Comment: You might be messing up with location of folder where you have stored typeface. Have a look

Comment: @TimKranen sure, will update when I find it.

Comment: @bipin yes, tried various combinations, including "fonts/xx" and "assets/fonts/xx". Included update as edit in main Q.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Native typeface cannot be made" only for some people](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people)

Comment: I have to say you are not alone. I also did an update of my android studio and now my typeface is miss-behaving. I am not sure what could be the problem. I suspect it is a bug. Have you tried updating you gradle?

Answer (score 1):

Ok there is a bug in android! This should work!

```
public class Typefaces {
    private static final String TAG = "Typefaces";

    private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

        public static Typeface get(Context c, String assetPath) {
            synchronized (cache) {
                if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
                    try {
                        Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                                assetPath);
                        cache.put(assetPath, t);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface '" + assetPath
                                + "' because " + e.getMessage());
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return cache.get(assetPath);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now just call `Typefaces.get(this,"address of font here")`
I referred from  [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people)
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at where your font is. If its in assets/fonts then the code for typeface should be:

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
```

Comment: Tried that too, just confirmed again – does not solve problem. Yes, the font file is in assets/fonts.

Comment: Well that's one fix done. Can you post a log? Also check if your textView is nulk or not, is the id of the locsted textView in the layout? Does it exist?

Comment: Working on the log part (how do I plug logcat in without making a mess?), but the id ("hometext") has been rechecked at the layout file and definitely tallies.

Comment: Got the logcat up, on main post.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for related questions first, because it says that TypeFace cannot be made. Did you give the correct path? If so, test other fonts too.

Same problem from before:
["Native typeface cannot be made" only for some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people)

Also, use the Fontify Library for Android. It makes everything much easier and better!

URL:
https://github.com/danh32/Fontify

Comment: Yes, actually I took extra care to do an extensive search (to as far as my keywords could take me – due to lack of experience in Android dev) as I crafted my question for similar / exact 'Q's, but the abovementioned link didn't show up due to choice of words in title (I suppose). Also, not familiar with reading logcats.. apologies for that. Thanks for everything, really helped me as a starter.

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if you can fix it, else, I can write a sample source code for you if you want. Send me an email with your application and I can fix it for you. My email is Xarialon@gmail.com