# supporting non-english characters in android

Tags: android, language-agnostic, fonts

I want to know that how good is android when supporting non-english characters? Is it possible to embed fonts in my app and make the app to use that font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system fonts already support Unicode language very well (as well as Eclipse, but you will have to select new encoding when saving, Eclipse will confirm this).

You can embed your fonts as well. Look at [this tutorial](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-use-external-fonts-android) and [this discusstion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font).

More information: I'm working on Vietnamese. The system is perfect for Vietnamese, and I think it is for other languages, too.

Comment: @Mikeveli Sorry, it's my mistake. I mean Unicode (I intend to use non-ASCII).

Comment: No worries, it makes sense now. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

FYI the emulator with android 2.3.3 support hebrew characters.

But you can use your own fonts if you want.
Place them in the `res/assets` folder, then

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "my_font.ttf");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer for a japanese company and i've hadno problems with japanese characters even on devices set for english. However, if you want to use custom fonts, use vvieux's code :)