# Use Roboto font for earlier devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fonts

I would like to use the Roboto font in my Android application and make sure it works for earlier versions of Android that don't have the font installed.  I know I can do this by using Typeface.createFromAsset() and then manually setting the font for each of my TextViews/Buttons/Other-Objects.  It seems like a big pain to do this for every object I show on the screen though.

My question is, is there a better way to do this?  Some helper class or a way to set a custom font in a .xml theme file?  Anything automated would be better than manually listing out every object on each screen and changing the font.

Thanks!

Comment: You can put it in a [style](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) maybe. Idk if that works with typefaces from assets though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Retrieve all views inside activity, check its type and apply appropriate action.

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
for (View view : allViews)
{
 if (view instanceof TextView) 
 {
    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
    textView.setTypeface(typeface);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Above accepted answer is correct but I just wanted to supply my implementation here

My utility class:

```
package com.example.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidUtils
{
    private static Typeface robotoTypeFace;

    public static void setRobotoFont (Context context, View view)
    {
        if (robotoTypeFace == null)
        {
            robotoTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        }
        setFont(view, robotoTypeFace);
    }

    private static void setFont (View view, Typeface robotoTypeFace)
    {
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                setFont(((ViewGroup)view).getChildAt(i), robotoTypeFace);
            }
        }
        else if (view instanceof TextView)
        {
            ((TextView) view).setTypeface(robotoTypeFace);
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it, assuming `this` is an Activity:

```
AndroidUtils.setRobotoFont(this, view);
```

To set the same font to all the TextView you can use the decorView of your activity:

```
ViewGroup godfatherView = (ViewGroup)this.getWindow().getDecorView();
AndroidUtils.setRobotoFont(this, godfatherView);
```

If you have adapters or fragments, don't forget to set their font as well.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10184068/410712) also.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @Jitsu, @Arnaud and @Pawan M, I made my solution, better than all of them alone:

```
/**
 * Adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/12387343/450148
 *
 * @author Anton Averin
 * @author Felipe Micaroni Lalli
 */

package net.alouw.alouwCheckin.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

public final class FontUtils {
    private FontUtils() {
    }

    private enum FontType {
        BOLD("fonts/Roboto/Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf"),
        BOLD_ITALIC("fonts/Roboto/Roboto-BoldCondensedItalic.ttf"),
        NORMAL("fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Condensed.ttf"),
        ITALIC("fonts/Roboto/Roboto-CondensedItalic.ttf");

        private final String path;

        FontType(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }
    }

    /* cache for loaded Roboto typefaces*/
    private static Map<FontType, Typeface> typefaceCache = new EnumMap<FontType, Typeface>(FontType.class);

    /**
     * Creates Roboto typeface and puts it into cache
     */
    private static Typeface getRobotoTypeface(Context context, FontType fontType) {
        String fontPath = fontType.getPath();

        if (!typefaceCache.containsKey(fontType)) {
            typefaceCache.put(fontType, Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontPath));
        }

        return typefaceCache.get(fontType);
    }

    /**
     * Gets roboto typeface according to passed typeface style settings.
     * <p/>
     * Will get Roboto-Bold for Typeface.BOLD etc
     */
    private static Typeface getRobotoTypeface(Context context, Typeface originalTypeface) {
        FontType robotoFontType = null;

        if (originalTypeface == null) {
            robotoFontType = FontType.NORMAL;
        } else {
            int style = originalTypeface.getStyle();

            switch (style) {
                case Typeface.BOLD:
                    robotoFontType = FontType.BOLD;
                    break;

                case Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC:
                    robotoFontType = FontType.BOLD_ITALIC;
                    break;

                case Typeface.ITALIC:
                    robotoFontType = FontType.ITALIC;
                    break;

                case Typeface.NORMAL:
                    robotoFontType = FontType.NORMAL;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return (robotoFontType == null) ? originalTypeface : getRobotoTypeface(context, robotoFontType);
    }

    /**
     * Walks ViewGroups, finds TextViews and applies Typefaces taking styling in consideration
     *
     * @param context - to reach assets
     * @param view    - root view to apply typeface to
     */
    public static void setRobotoFont(Context context, View view) {
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                setRobotoFont(context, ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
        } else if (view instanceof TextView) {
            Typeface currentTypeface = ((TextView) view).getTypeface();
            ((TextView) view).setTypeface(getRobotoTypeface(context, currentTypeface));
        }
    }
}
```

And the last thing in your onCreate main activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
    ViewGroup godfatherView = (ViewGroup) this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    FontUtils.setRobotoFont(this, godfatherView);
}
```

And in my lists with custom views the code above didn't work, so I had to make this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // (...)

    View view = // build your custom view here

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        FontUtils.setRobotoFont(activity, view);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Hi think it's `(if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 11))` no?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my improved version of this solution.
It can cache fonts and takes into consideration TextView.textStyle parameter settings. So it can set bold text.
http://anton.averin.pro/2012/09/12/how-to-use-android-roboto-font-in-honeycomb-and-earlier-versions/

Comment: Very good! Using with << ViewGroup godfatherView = (ViewGroup)this.getWindow().getDecorView();
AndroidUtils.setRobotoFont(this, godfatherView); >> is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

I use another solution. I set custom [LayoutInflater.Factory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.Factory.html) to activity. So I have full access to view after it creating. I can install custom font for every TextView without iterating on view hierarchy. One thing you should do to use custom font in all your application is call `new Font(...).install()` in your base activity. See exaple below.

Here is my solution with sample of usage:

```
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.collect.Maps;

import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Provides an ability to apply custom font to all {@link TextView} and subclasses.
 *
 * To install custom font use method {@link #install(Activity)} in {@link Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)}
 * <b>before</b> calling super.onCreate(Bundle).
 *
 * <p/>Example of usage:
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * public class BaseActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
 *
 *      protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
 *          applyCustomFontForPreICS();
 *          super.onCreate(state);
 *      }
 *
 *      private void applyCustomFontForPreICS() {
 *          boolean isPreICS = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < BUILD_VERSION_CODE_ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH
 *          if (isPreICS) {
 *              new Font(
 *                  "font/roboto_regular.ttf",
 *                  "font/roboto_bold.ttf",
 *                  "font/roboto_italic.ttf",
 *                  "font/roboto_bold_italic.ttf"
 *              ).install(this);
 *          }
 *      }
 * }
 * }
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @author Alexey Danilov (danikula@gmail.com)
 */
public class Font {

    private static final Map<String, Typeface> FONTS = Maps.newHashMap();

    private String regularFontPath;
    private String boldFontPath;
    private String italicFontPath;
    private String boldItalicFontPath;

    /**
     * Creates instance to be used for setting particular font.
     *
     * @param regularPath regular font assets path, must be not {@code null}
     * @param boldPath bold font assets path, must be not {@code null}
     * @param italicPath italic font assets path, must be not {@code null}
     * @param boldItalicPath bold and italic font assets path, must be not {@code null}
     */
    public Font(String regularPath, String boldPath, String italicPath, String boldItalicPath) {
        this.regularFontPath = checkNotNull(regularPath);
        this.boldFontPath = checkNotNull(boldPath);
        this.italicFontPath = checkNotNull(italicPath);
        this.boldItalicFontPath = checkNotNull(boldItalicPath);
    }

    /**
     * Installs custom font to activity.
     *
     * @param activity an activity custom font will be installed to, must be not {@code null}.
     */
    public void install(Activity activity) {
        checkNotNull(activity, "Activity must be not null!");

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        boolean factoryIsEmpty = layoutInflater.getFactory() == null;
        if (!factoryIsEmpty) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Impossible to use this method for this activity: layout factory is set!");
        }
        layoutInflater.setFactory(new FontLayoutInflaterFactory());
    }

    private Typeface getFont(int type, Context context) {
        switch (type) {
            case Typeface.NORMAL:
                return getFont(context, regularFontPath);
            case Typeface.BOLD:
                return getFont(context, boldFontPath);
            case Typeface.ITALIC:
                return getFont(context, italicFontPath);
            case Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC:
                return getFont(context, boldItalicFontPath);
            default: {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Undefined font type " + type);
            }
        }
    }

    private Typeface getFont(Context context, String path) {
        if (FONTS.containsKey(path)) {
            return FONTS.get(path);
        } else {
            Typeface typeface = makeTypeface(context, path);
            FONTS.put(path, typeface);
            return typeface;
        }
    }

    private Typeface makeTypeface(Context context, String path) {
        try {
            return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // add user-friendly error message
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Error creating font from assets path '%s'", path), e);
        }
    }

    private void applyFontToTextView(Context context, TextView textView, AttributeSet attrs) {
        int[] fontStyleAttributes = {R.attr.textStyle};
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, fontStyleAttributes);
        boolean isStyleSpecified = typedArray.getIndexCount() != 0;
        int type = isStyleSpecified ? typedArray.getInt(0, Typeface.NORMAL) : Typeface.NORMAL;
        Typeface font = getFont(type, context);
        textView.setTypeface(font, type);
    }

    private final class FontLayoutInflaterFactory implements LayoutInflater.Factory {

        // to improve perfomance the package with the most usable components should be the first.
        private final String[] ANDROID_UI_COMPONENT_PACKAGES = {
                "android.widget.",
                "android.webkit.",
                "android.view."
        };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            try {
                // we install custom LayoutInflater.Factory, so FragmentActivity have no chance set own factory and
                // inflate tag <fragment> in method onCreateView. So  call it explicitly.
                if ("fragment".equals(name) && context instanceof FragmentActivity) {
                    FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity) context;
                    return fragmentActivity.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
                }

                View view = createView(name, attrs, LayoutInflater.from(context));
                if (view == null) {
                    // It's strange! The view is not ours neither android's. May be the package of this view
                    // is not listed in ANDROID_UI_COMPONENT_PACKAGES. Return null for the default behavior.
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cannot create view with name: " + name);
                    return null;
                }

                if (view instanceof TextView) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
                    applyFontToTextView(context, textView, attrs);
                }
                return view;
            } catch (InflateException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error inflating view", e);
                return null;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error inflating view", e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private View createView(String name, AttributeSet attrs, LayoutInflater layoutInflater) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            View view = null;
            boolean isAndroidComponent = name.indexOf('.') == -1;
            if (isAndroidComponent) {
                // We don't know package name of the view with the given simple name. Try android ui packages listed in
                // ANDROID_UI_COMPONENT_PACKAGES

                // The same implementation is in the class PhoneLayoutInflater from internal API
                for (String androidPackage : ANDROID_UI_COMPONENT_PACKAGES) {
                    try {
                        view = layoutInflater.createView(name, androidPackage, attrs);
                        if (view != null) {
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // Do nothing, we will try another package
                    }
                }
            } else {
                view = layoutInflater.createView(name, null, attrs);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Note it has dependency on [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), but you can implement this methods by himself.

Answer (score 3):

The best sollution ever is [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)