# How to use Custom font in eclipse?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Using Custom Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font)

i am creating an application in arabic
and have a custom font that i want to use
can someone tell me the code i should use in my java class
i tried this

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "trado.ttf");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

but the ending line that says font theres an error that says
Syntax error on token "font", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
Can someone help!

Comment: Duplicated post, see Android - Using Custom Font http://stackoverflow.com/q/3651086/594773

Comment: Everything is fine here, have you added the font to the Assets folder?

Comment: yes i did but i get an error!

Comment: write exactly the error, your code seems to be fine.

Comment: VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this, as in adding `this` lol

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "trado.ttf");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 2):

Save your custom font file in a folder `fonts` inside the `assets` folder.

for example:

```
assets/fonts/trado.ttf
```

[image]

and make sure your font extension (i.e **ttf** in your case) is in lower case.

Comment: I already found how to do this