# Efficient Way to customize Font

Tags: android, memory, fonts, textview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Using Custom Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font)

What's the best or Efficient way to Customize the font in An Android APPlication? I have been trying to customize my Textviews and Edittexts, but my application is kind of slow because I'm using custom fonts and takes a lot of memory and sometimes even crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seriously doubt the slowness in your application is a result of you using custom fonts. It's probably the way you're applying them. Typically, I'll do something like the following in my Activity:

```
//Get an instance to the root of your layout (outermost XML tag in your layout
//document)
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.my_root_viewgroup);

//Get one reference to your Typeface (placed in your assets folder)
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "My-Font.ttf");

//Call setTypeface with this root and font
setTypeface(root, font);

public void setTypeface(ViewGroup root, Typeface font) {
    View v;

    //Cycle through all children
    for(int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++) {
        v = root.getChildAt(i);

        //If it's a TextView (or subclass, such as Button) set the font
        if(v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView)v).setTypeface(font);

        //If it's another ViewGroup, make a recursive call
        } else if(v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            setTypeface(v, font);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you keep only one reference to your Typeface, and you don't have to hard code any of your View IDs.

You can also just build this into a custom subclass of `Activity`, and then have all of your Activites extend your custom Activity instead of just extending Activity, then you only have to write this code once.

Comment: This wouldn't consume a lot of memory?

Comment: Nope. Out of curiosity, why do you think it would?

Comment: You are setting typeface everytime you get a TextView, so for  each textView it wouldn't allocate memory separately? beside this am using a ListView with tons of items.

Comment: Yeah, I do this in my ListViews with hundreds of items with no problem. As long as it's a class variable and you're not creating a new Typeface reference for every item, it's going to be using the same Typeface reference for every TextView.

Comment: What if Im inflating layouts in my application, How can I do it then?

Comment: Just call setTypeface on that layout you inflate instead of the one you find with `findViewById()`. You can pass in *any* ViewGroup to that method and it will work, whether you find it by ID or inflate in in code.