# Android + TextView + text like made by old typewriter

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I want to make `TextView` with text, which looks like made by old typewriter on metallic background. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: have you tried using custom font that looks like typewriter fonts..

Answer (score 1):

You can use specific [background](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background) for `TextView` and [custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font) for text.