# Showing the superscript character ⁵ in a TextView for Android

Tags: android, textview

I would like to show the character ⁵ in a TextView for Android. Not 5, but ⁵.
I succeed in showing ¹²³ and ⁴, but ⁵ to ⁹ (and ⁰) don't work (it is replaced by a blank space)

For several reasons, I don't want to use html tags, so I write the characters in the xml the way I want them to appear, not with `<sup></sup>`.

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work for ⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰ ?
Do you know how to solve the problem ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: It could depend of the font, and you want Unicode characters for that.

Comment: chances are these characters don't exist in your font. However, the HTML version would surely work.

Answer (score 0):

`5` - exists, but it is not visible.  It just takes up space. 
 May be it is a bug with the font. 
Try to use another. [How to set custom font](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/)

Or try to use [unicode directly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)

For ex. `\u2075`

Hope it's help

Comment: OK. So I just tried \u2075, and it's all the same. Except that this time, I tried on another device, and both ⁵ and \u2075 are replace by and empty square. I'm going to try another font.

Comment: Yes, I think it just font bug, but please, add comment will decide whether to change the font problem.

Comment: what do you mean 'the unicode directly' ? these characters don't exist in iso, the android xml files are utf-8, and the characters or they unicode value are identical, aren't they ?

Comment: si I just tried serif, freemono, monospace, sans and normal (that's all what eclipse accepts) with android:typeface="normal", and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @jimpanzer : What do you mean by "add comment will decide whether to change the font problem" ?

Comment: @njzk2, just try to do this,  android:text="@string/string_with_unicode", where   <string name="string_with_unicode">\u00A9 StackOverflow</string> and you understand what I mean.

Comment: A9 is ©, i still don't see the difference between one and the other?

Answer (score 0):

Your font apparently doesn't support this section of Unicode (U+2070 to U+209F)

You can include your own font in your app and use it for these textViews. (see [Android - Using Custom Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font))