# Android doesn't recognize the \u202A and \u202c

Tags: android, string, unicode, textview

As the title says, it shows them as static string. I have a string from database written in Arabic. I place some English text in between some Arabic one (the English one contains numbers and * and #). Android doesn't recognize the RTL embedding characters (iOS do BTW).

Comment: Please confirm the Android version you are testing against as native RTL wasn't available until 4.2. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: I am testing on 4.1.2. Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the issue here: 
[String concatenation containing Arabic and Western characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177294/string-concatenation-containing-arabic-and-western-characters)

I found out that I was using `"\U202C"` instead of `\u202C"` (Captial "U" made it unrecognizable). Once replace with small U, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom font.

You should be able to find a suitable ttf file by doing a quick search.

This outlines the general approach.

[Some unicodes in Android EditText can not show correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439674/some-unicodes-in-android-edittext-can-not-show-correctly/17560325#17560325)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the font. The characters work as intended but they shall not appear! Not good answer, "Sheldon" :)

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood ! Normally, when I enter a unicode and it doesn't appear it is because the unicode character is not supported in the standard android font. To display such characters I use a custom font. But let's not fall out over this - I don't have any more space on my "mortal enemy" list ! :-)