# android: font family for whole app

Tags: java, android

I don't want to use the default font for my app.

I want to use my desired font.

Therefore, I copied my desired font in `assets/fonts/` folder and coded as shown below.

However, an error occurs.

Please help me use the same font for the full app.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
    this.setContentView(ll);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "fonts/TAU_MADN.TTF");
    tv.setTypeface(face);
```

UPDATE:

My xml `TextView` code;

```
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Error:

> error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'id' with value 'app_name').

Comment: what error it is showing

Comment: You need to add the stack trace from LogCat to your question. Otherwise helping you is guess work at best.

Comment: On a side note, whatever your error may be, the code you posted will only use the custom font within the `Activity`'s scope, for that specific `TextView`.

Comment: edited with error showing

Comment: can you show your layout `activity_main`?

Comment: You ID attribute is wrong. It should be like this: `android:id="@+id/app_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with the loading of the custom font as an asset.

In your layout `R.layout.activity_main` there is no `TextView` with id: `R.id.app_name`, therefore when you initialize that `TextView` in your code the error will thrown.

Make sure you have such `TextView` in your layout.

If you think you **do** have that `TextView` in the layout already, try and clean the project.

**Edit**

Add the id as below:

```
android:id="@+id/app_name"
```

Also rename your font with lowercased ".ttf" extension, and the reference to it all the same.

```
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "fonts/TAU_MADN.ttf"); // lowercased ".ttf" reference
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font) for more info on your issue.

Comment: Error removed now. But fonts are not changing

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the path has been given correctly, like case sensitives stuffs including the extension.TTF or .ttf {same name as in the fonts folder} including the folder name "FONTS"!.

Comment: It's .TTF only. Error is app_name cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: comment the codes for font and just run it... Is it showing the same error again?

Comment: Error:

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);

    app_name cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Have you given app_name as an id for TextView in the XML file or else by mistake Button or something else??

Comment: i have added my textview now

Comment: Replace that code 

     android:id="@+id/R.id.app_name"

with

     android:id="@+id/app_name"

Comment: Errors are removed. But Fonts are not changing to mentioned font family

Answer (score 0):

May this help you:

Change `android:id` attribute in your **TextView** Like:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

And also change this line in your code:

```
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "fonts/TAU_MADN.ttf");
```

Comment: I re-upvoted your answer now that you have edited it to show working code.

Answer (score 0):

Android allows integer type ids only

You mention string type id thats your mistake

Change this Line

```
android:id="app_name"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/app_name"
```