# Android: Use custom font with Custom Adapter using SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, custom-adapter, custom-font

How can I input a text with a custom font, put it to SQLite and then display it in a textview?

I can set font for the EditText and TextView, but I want to get the Typeface from the EditText and put it into the TextView (in my case a text in a ListView)

You can assume my app as a chat application with custom font.

Thanks

Comment: working with custom fonts is a pain in android I am currently doing it too you might want to try this library to make things easier https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Answer (score 0):

OK first, the font doesn't have anything to do with the database. So I'm gonna help you here by pointing you in the right direction:

Here's a tutorial on how to save to a database: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html (Read it, it's a good one).

And besides, once you want to display your data into a `TextView` THEN you should set a font to said `TextView`: [Android - Using Custom Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font)

Comment: Thanks man! I can do both above, what I need, however, is to display a listview with custom font (and each element can have any font as I chose before)

Answer (score 0):

From what you're describing I'm imagining a ListView which represents a chat thread/log. Each item in the ListView (in this case a TextView) represents a single message. Each message in the chat thread can have a custom font. You want to persist the message's font type to the database. Essentially, you want to change a TextView's font using a custom adapter.

To do this, I would create a `Message` object. This `Message` object would have fields (i.e. variables) on it like `MessageContent`, `MessageFont` etc. You could then persist this object to your database. Upon retrieval from the database, you could then use a custom adapter to assign the font to your TextView.

```
public class MessageCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private Cursor messageCursor;
private Context context;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public MessageCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor);
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_item_text);

    String messageFont = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name_of_database_column"));
    if (messageFont.equals("Epimodem")) {
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/epimodem.ttf");
    messageTextView.setTypeface(face);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_item, parent, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want to do. Can you show me a working example of using this Adapter? I kinda new to this.

Comment: @coderkisser I have already included an example of a custom cursor adapter. What else is unclear to you?

Comment: Your Adapter is nice, but MessageCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) is deprecated, should be changed to MessageCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, false)

Answer (score 0):

In any Adapter Class that you Extend to populate the data you get a Function named [getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29). What you want can be done here.

What you need to do is to create a Class that extends an adapter and then inflate the view that you are going to return and want to be displayed and then on the TextView set the TypeFaces.

```
 @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    // Set the TypeFace Here
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");
    textView.setTypeface(font);

     return rowView;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I don't have a textView id, I just have a ListView in my layout, how can I set TypeFace for the textView inside it. In other words, how can I find the texts in my listView?

Comment: Seems like you really don't know about listviews but you have to create a Custom Separate layout XML for that and add an ID to your  TextViews. you can check this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: honestly I haven't figured out how to use your getView(), I have many different Textviews in the ListView and I need to find some way to identify each of them.