# Rounded edges default font in Android textview

Tags: android, fonts

Is there a default font or font-combination for android in fontFamily or typeface that has rounded edges in each letter, similar to comic sans?

The reason why is because I am trying to display a bubbly like font that has smoothly-rounded edges for each letter.

I have looked around the web for a while and haven't been able to find a simple solution because I don't want to use other libraries or import a font for various reasons (e.g. memory, space, etc.) in my android project files. It shouldn't be this hard to find this but has taken me awhile for some reason.

Comment: if you are looking for performance wise application then ttf is a way to go, else you will customize your character, and drawing it with radius border on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such font, you need to add a .ttf file for the typeface you want.

This site has a lot of free fonts like what you're looking for.  The first one I looked at has a file size of only 50kb.
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/classification/comic

See [Android - Using Custom Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font) for how to add it.