# How can i force samsung phones to use my own font in my app?

Tags: android

i use this code to change fonts of textview on my app

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");  
    tvDesc.setTypeface(tf);
```

but the problem is, this only works on nexus devices, when i install my app on a samsung, it uses it's own font.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font Where did you put your `fonts` folder ? Under `res` folder or under `assets` folder ?

Comment: you are creating typeface variable called `tf2` and setting typeface to the textview as `tf` . Is this correct ?

Comment: this is just a mistake on typing the question, actually on my code both are tf
My fonts are in assets folder

Comment: Did you find any solution?