# custom police (myriad pro ) for android application

Tags: android

i want to use a custom police for my android application (myriad pro regular), where can i find it. i mean an android font like saxmono.ttf

Comment: police? This site is for programming questions. We are not here to find a rent-a-cop service for you. If you mean font, then the same thing holds.

Comment: i'm talking about font like saxmono.ttf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Myriad%20Pro%20Regular) turns up a number of sites offering the Myriad Pro Regular font.

To use this in Android, you have a few options:

- Use a library such as [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)
- Use a custom TextView subclass such as the one described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26089326/1253844)
- Call [`setTypeFace()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)) directly on all the TextViews you want to use your font with.