# Add font in class not Activity android

Tags: android, fonts

I've read how to add font in Android, but how to do this in class that is not Activity. I've put this font: lokikola.ttf in src/main/assets/fonts.

Here is my code:

MyAdapter.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import at.technikum.mti.fancycoverflow.FancyCoverFlow;
import at.technikum.mti.fancycoverflow.FancyCoverFlowAdapter;

public class MyAdapter extends FancyCoverFlowAdapter{

    private int[] images = {R.drawable.rain, R.drawable.forest, R.drawable.wave, R.drawable.leaf};
    private String[] nameImage = {"Rain", "Forest", "Wave", "Jungle"};
    private Context mContext;
    Typeface type;


    public MyAdapter(Context mContext){
        this.mContext=mContext;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer getItem(int i) {
        return images[i];
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }


    @Override
    public View getCoverFlowItem(int i, View reuseableView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        reuseableView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, viewGroup, false);

        RelativeLayout rlMain =(RelativeLayout) reuseableView.findViewById(R.id.rlMain);
        rlMain.setLayoutParams(new FancyCoverFlow.LayoutParams(600,600));
        TextView txtName = (TextView) reuseableView.findViewById(R.id.txtNameimage);
        ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) reuseableView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        type = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/lokikola.ttf");
        txtName.setTypeface(type);

        txtName.setText(nameImage[i]);
        ivImage.setImageResource(images[i]);
        return reuseableView;
    }
}
```

When I run the program, it shows error at this line:
 `type = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/lokikola.ttf");`

So, how to fix it?

Comment: Where u have added `lokikola.ttf` font in assets?

Comment: I downloaded lokikola.ttf , then I put it into src/main/assets/fonts. What's wrong?

Comment: I follow this link guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview

Comment: Here is the answers for the similar question I've already answered please follow the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667144/is-it-possible-to-use-fancy-fonts-in-android/31667238#31667238

Comment: Try this:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm

Comment: it doesn't work, a lot of error

Comment: Could you post the logcat error please?

Comment: please go to chat room for me to easy post this logcat error

Comment: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class ease.fantageek.com.ease.NeutraBoldTextView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

Comment: Did you make sure you wrote the file name correctly in code?

Comment: Also did you try writing getAssets() instantly instead of mContext.getAssets()?

Comment: This seems like a bug. Could you please try it on some more devices and see if all of them crash? Please do check if the file name and the extension are in the same case. Sometimes .ttf files come as .TTF (CAPS)

Comment: OK! Sorry guys, I forgot some easy things. This issue has been resolved.