# Use weathericons.io in Android?

Tags: android

[This is a pack of free weather icons](http://weathericons.io) that I like.
It's made for CSS/HTML.
How can I type out those special characters in a textview? f00d, f02e etc

Comment: It looks like it is an icon font. Presumably, you would use it like any other custom font.

Comment: To answer your question, yes. :)

Comment: If you have not tried yet to write code to use these then this is not the place to ask the question

Comment: But how do I type out special characters like f00d or f02e ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a custom font for that icon pack.

Check any related tutorial about using a custom font in android, or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font) for example.

Also you can use a dedicated library like [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy).