# how to change font in a fragment, android?

Tags: android

Code example:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

How can I change the font, but not activity in the Fragment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Using Custom Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line

```
android:fontFamily="@font/hind_bold"
```

replace your fount name with **hind_bold**