# How do you change text to bold in Android?

Tags: android, text, textview

How do you change **text/font** settings in an Android **`TextView`**?

For example, how do you make the text **bold**?

Comment: Please check my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40802895/1252158).
Hope this will help you

Comment: [click here](https://androidride.com/android-textview-bold/)

Answer (score 648):

To do this in the `layout.xml` file:

```
android:textStyle
```

Examples:

```
android:textStyle="bold|italic"
```

Programmatically the method is:

```
setTypeface(Typeface tf)
```

Sets the typeface and style in which the text should be displayed. Note that not all `Typeface` families actually have bold and italic variants, so you may need to use `setTypeface(Typeface, int)` to get the appearance that you actually want.

Answer (score 381):

Here is the solution

```
TextView questionValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.TextView01);
questionValue.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: what if the editTextView components,,... is it possible to bold each line differently?

Comment: Yes Its possible

Answer (score 89):

Simply you can do the following:

Set the attribute in `XML`

```
  android:textStyle="bold"
```

Programatically the method is:

```
TextView Tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);

Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD);

Tv.setTypeface(boldTypeface);
```

Hope this helps you thank you.

Comment: Let me know the result

Answer (score 55):

In XML

```
android:textStyle="bold" //only bold
android:textStyle="italic" //only italic
android:textStyle="bold|italic" //bold & italic
```

You can only use specific fonts `sans`, `serif` & `monospace` via xml, [Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9199258/2459296) can use custom fonts

```
android:typeface="monospace" // or sans or serif
```

Programmatically (Java code)

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);

textView.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF); //only font style
textView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD); //only text style(only bold)
textView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC); //only text style(bold & italic)
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF,Typeface.BOLD); 
                                         //font style & text style(only bold)
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF,Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                                         //font style & text style(bold & italic)
```

Answer (score 28):

For case where you are using custom fonts, but do not have bold typeface for the font you can use:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + myText + "</b>");
```

Answer (score 28):

From the XML you can set the **textStyle** to **bold** as below

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Bold text"
   android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

You can set the TextView to bold programmatically as below

```
textview.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

Answer (score 22):

Set the attribute

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

Answer (score 22):

It's very easy

```
setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

Answer (score 20):

Through XML:

```
 android:textStyle="bold"
```

Through Java:

```
//Let's say you have a textview 
textview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 17):

If you're drawing it then this will do it:

```
TextPaint.setFlags(Paint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 16):

In the ideal world you would set the text style attribute in you layout XML definition like that:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

There is a simple way to achieve the same result dynamically in your code by using **`setTypeface`** method. You need to pass and object of **Typeface** class, which will describe the font style for that TextView. So to achieve the same result as with the XML definition above you can do the following:

```
TextView Tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD);
Tv.setTypeface(boldTypeface);
```

The first line will create the object form predefined style (in this case **Typeface.BOLD**, but there are many more predefined). Once we have an instance of typeface we can set it on the TextView. And that's it our content will be displayed on the style we defined.

I hope it helps you a lot.For better info you can visit

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html

Answer (score 11):

Define a new style with the format you want in the style.xml file in the values folder

```
<style name="TextViewStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#5EADED</item>

</style>
```

Then apply this style to the TextView by writing the following code with the properties of the TextView

```
style="@style/TextViewStyle"
```

Answer (score 10):

in **file .xml**, set

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

will set text type is bold.

Answer (score 9):

The best way to go is:

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

Answer (score 8):

[4 ways to make Android TextView bold](https://androidride.com/android-textview-bold/)- Full answer is here.

1. Using **android:textStyle** attribute

   `<TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="TEXTVIEW 1"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       />`

   Use bold|italic for bold and italic.
2. using setTypeface() method

   ```
   textview2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
   textview2.setText("TEXTVIEW 2");
   ```
3. HtmlCompat.fromHtml() method, Html.fromHtml() was deprecated in API level 24.

   ```
    String html="This is <b>TEXTVIEW 3</b>";
    textview3.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html,Typeface.BOLD));
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are a new starter on Android Studio,
Simply you can get it done in design view **XML** by using

```
android:textStyle="bold"          //to make text bold
android:textStyle="italic"        //to make text italic
android:textStyle="bold|italic"   //to make text bold & italic
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, Passing value through string.xml worked out with html Tag..

`<string name="your_string_tag"> <b> your_text </b></string>`

Answer (score 5):

You can use this for font

create a Class Name TypefaceTextView and extend the TextView

private static Map mTypefaces;

```
public TypefaceTextView(final Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public TypefaceTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TypefaceTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    if (mTypefaces == null) {
        mTypefaces = new HashMap<String, Typeface>();
    }

    if (this.isInEditMode()) {
        return;
    }

    final TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, styleable.TypefaceTextView);
    if (array != null) {
        final String typefaceAssetPath = array.getString(
                R.styleable.TypefaceTextView_customTypeface);

        if (typefaceAssetPath != null) {
            Typeface typeface = null;

            if (mTypefaces.containsKey(typefaceAssetPath)) {
                typeface = mTypefaces.get(typefaceAssetPath);
            } else {
                AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, typefaceAssetPath);
                mTypefaces.put(typefaceAssetPath, typeface);
            }

            setTypeface(typeface);
        }
        array.recycle();
    }
}
```

paste the font in the fonts folder created in the asset folder

```
<packagename.TypefaceTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TRENDING TURFS"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:customTypeface="fonts/pompiere.ttf" />**here pompiere.ttf is the font name**
```

Place the lines  in the parent layout in the xml

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mediasters.wheresmyturf"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
editText.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), ttfFilePath));
etitText.setTypeface(et.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

will set both typface as well as style to Bold.

Comment: You should include a brief explanation of your answer to better describe its use case and implementation.

Comment: This does not ad anything new to the existing answers.

Comment: @nvoigt, his answer differs from many others, at least the second line. Probably it is better than other solutions. I think it is captured from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200533/set-textview-style-bold-or-italic/42484530.

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin we can do in one line

```
 TEXT_VIEW_ID.typeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
ty.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/magistral.ttf"), Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: StackOverflow requires answers to be posted in English.

Comment: Use the translator!

Comment: No, it is your responsibility to post in English, otherwise you can use https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score -2):

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG)
```

To remove, use

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG)
```

Or in Kotlin:

```
fun TextView.makeBold() {
    this.paintFlags = this.paintFlags or Paint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG
}

fun TextView.removeBold() {
    this.paintFlags = this.paintFlags and (Paint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG.inv())
}
```