# TextView bold via XML file?

Tags: android, textview, resources

Is there a way to bold the text in a TextView via XML?

```
<TextView
   android:textSize="12dip"
   android:textAppearance="bold"  -> ??
</TextView>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you change text to bold in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792260/how-do-you-change-text-to-bold-in-android)

Comment: `android:textStyle="bold"`

Answer (score 508, accepted):

I have a project in which I have the following `TextView` :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
/>
```

So, I'm guessing you need to use [**`android:textStyle`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textStyle)

Comment: I'm using like this with library


`<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="@string/start"
            android:textAppearance="@style/PtSansNarrowFont"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />`

style.xml
`<style name="PtSansNarrowFont" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Custom Attr-->
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/pt-sans_narrow.ttf</item>
    </style>`
**not applying bold**

Answer (score 31):

just use

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

Answer (score 10):

Example:

use:  `android:textStyle="bold"`

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtVelocidade"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtlatitude"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Aguardando GPS"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `android:textStyle="bold"`

[4 ways to make Android TextView Bold](https://androidride.com/android-textview-bold/)

like this

```
<TextView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:textSize="12dip"
android:textStyle="bold"
/>
```

There are many ways to make Android TextView bold.

Answer (score 4):

use textstyle property as bold

```
android:textStyle = "bold";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Just you need to use 

//for bold
android:textStyle="bold"

//for italic
android:textStyle="italic"

//for normal
android:textStyle="normal"

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/userName"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:textSize="16sp"
/>
```