# How to set TextView textStyle such as bold, italic

Tags: android, textview, styles

How to set `TextView` style (bold or italic) within Java and without using the XML layout?

In other words, I need to write `android:textStyle` with Java.

Answer (score 2101, accepted):

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

To keep the previous typeface

```
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)
```

Comment: To remove the style can be used Typeface.NORMAL

Comment: If you do that, you'll lose any previous typeface. To keep the previous one, do something like
    textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);

Comment: `textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);` will not remove bold or italic styling from a `TextView`. You will need to use `textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);` for that.

Comment: To keep any previous typeface but to get rid of bold or italic style, use following code : `textView.setTypeface(Typeface.create(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL), Typeface.NORMAL);`

Comment: Thanks @Shnkc, You pointed me to the right direction. Actually you just need: textView.setTypeface(Typeface.create(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL));

Comment: You mean, you can't just do a bitwise OR when you want _both_ bold and italic?

Comment: @leocadiotine What do you mean by losing the typeface? If I set a custom font, will it go back to the default ones of the OS ?

Comment: Is there a "semi bold"? Font weight of 500?

Comment: for kotlin: textView.typeface = Typeface.create(textView.typeface, if (isSelected) Typeface.BOLD else Typeface.NORMAL)

Answer (score 290):

Try this to set on `TextView` for bold or italic

```
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to clear an existing typeface style, you'll need to do something different, e.g.: `tv.setTypeface(Typeface.create(tv.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL));`

Comment: @greg7gkb `tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);` won't this do the same(clear an existing typeface style)?

Comment: Passing null into setTypeface() means that the TextView uses a hard-coded default that may be different from the Typeface previously set.

Answer (score 166):

#### Programmatically:

You can do programmatically using `setTypeface()`:

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);      // for Normal Text
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);        // for Bold only
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);      // for Italic
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC); // for Bold and Italic
```

#### XML:

You can set Directly in XML file in `<TextView />` like:

```
android:textStyle="normal"
android:textStyle="normal|bold"
android:textStyle="normal|italic"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textStyle="bold|italic"
```

Comment: Questioner asked how to do it without using XML layout.

Comment: Check Question `with in Java and without using XML` By the way It will help to others also.

Comment: Yes. I came here via Google and it just helped me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 103):

You have two options:

**Option 1** (only works for bold, italic and underline):

```
String s = "<b>Bolded text</b>, <i>italic text</i>, even <u>underlined</u>!"
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.THE_TEXTVIEW_ID);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

**Option 2:**

Use a [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html); it is more complicated, but you can dynamically modify the text attributes (not only bold/italic, also colors).

Comment: Why not use the typeFace attribute?

Comment: With `typeFace` you can set a single style for the whole text.

Comment: when I am trying in my custom row its not getting why?  String s1 = "<b>You are at:</b>"; holder.address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address_text_view); holder.address.setText(Html.fromHtml(s1)+ track.getAddress());

Comment: This method is great partial text styling. Like a quote inside a large textview.

Comment: The first method doesn't work in my case  private void createTextView(String title, String text)
    {
        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(17);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + title + "</b>") + " : " + text);
    }

Comment: Option 1 is not works when we append some other text with this bolded text so in that case refer Option 2

Comment: The spannable and fromHTML options may slow down typing / setText if the text is big due to layout recalculations. Avoid it if you have other methods available.

Comment: tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("Test 1 2 3"));   This code can also be used easily.

Comment: <br> also works if you're looking for quick new lines between headings

Answer (score 54):

#### Programmatically:

You can do programmatically using `setTypeface()` method:

Below is the code for default Typeface

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);      // for Normal Text
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);        // for Bold only
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);      // for Italic
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC); // for Bold and Italic
```

and if you want to set *custom Typeface*:

```
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);      // for Normal Text
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);        // for Bold only
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);      // for Italic
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC); // for Bold and Italic
```

#### XML:

You can set directly in XML file in `<TextView />` like this:

```
android:textStyle="normal"
android:textStyle="normal|bold"
android:textStyle="normal|italic"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textStyle="bold|italic"
```

Or you can set your fav font (from assets). for more info [see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android/48642116#48642116)

Comment: I've been trying to use this way but when font is set to Typeface.BOLD, everything starts to act weird. Text gets collapsed (aligned vertically instead of horizontal, totally unreadable) and buttons stop responding, messes with listeners.. it goes to normal when i let the custom font Typeface.NORMAL.

Answer (score 15):

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.THE_TEXTVIEW_ID);
```

now set the `textview` properties..

```
text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);  //-- for only bold the text
text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);  //-- for  bold & italic the text
text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);  // -- for  italic the text
```

Answer (score 15):

You can set the different typeface using the example given below -

```
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

Or if you want to set a different font and its typeface . Add it to asset or raw folder and then use it like

```
  Typeface face= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/font.ttf");
  tv1.setTypeface(face);

  Typeface face1= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/font1.ttf");
  tv2.setTypeface(face1);
```

Answer (score 13):

Simply if you want to make text **bold**.
write this line in your layout in text view property

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

Answer (score 11):

It would be

```
yourTextView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

and italic should be able to be with replacing `Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD` with `Typeface.DEFAULT_ITALC`.

Let me know how it works.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

Answer (score 10):

try this to set your `TextView`  style by java code

```
txt1.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.layout.textName);
text.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

To keep the previous typeface

```
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `textView.setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style);` to set style property of the [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). See the [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface%29) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_idname);
textview.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 4):

Standard way to do this is to use the custom styles.
Ex-

In `styles.xml` add the following.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="MyApp.TextAppearance.LoginText">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
</style>
```

Apply this style to your `TextView` as follows.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/MyApp.TextAppearance.LoginText" />
```

Answer (score 4):

And as explained here [Android Developers String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) if you need to use parameters in your styled text resource, you have to escape the opening brackets

```
<resources>
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have &lt;b>%2$d new messages&lt;/b>.</string>
</resources>
```

and call formatHtml(string)

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages), username, mailCount);
CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
```

Answer (score 4):

One way you can do  is :

```
myTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
myTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
myTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
myTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Another option  if you want to keep the previous typeface and don't want to lose previously applied then:

```
myTextView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);      
myTextView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);        
myTextView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);      
myTextView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this:

```
<string name="title"><u><b><i>Your Text</i></b></u></string>
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way you can do based on the style selection criteria is:

```
String pre = "", post = "";

if(isBold){
    pre += "<b>"; post += "</b>";
}
if(isItalic){
    pre += "<i>"; post += "</i>";
}
if(isUnderline){
    pre += "<u>"; post += "</u>";
}

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(pre + editText.getText().toString()+ post));
// you can also use it with EidtText
editText.setText(Html.fromHtml(pre + editText.getText().toString()+ post));
```

Answer (score 3):

While using simplified tags with AndroidX consider using **HtmlCompat.fromHtml()**

```
String s = "<b>Bolded text</b>, <i>italic text</i>, even <u>underlined</u>!"    
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.THE_TEXTVIEW_ID);
tv.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(s, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I want to use a custom font only conjunction of several answers works for me. Obviously  settings in my `layout.xml` like `android:textStlyle="italic"` was ignored by AOS. So finally I had to do as follows:
in `strings.xml` the target string was declared as:

```
<string name="txt_sign"><i>The information blah blah ...</i></string>
```

then additionally in code:

```
TextView textSign = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_sign);
FontHelper.setSomeCustomFont(textSign);
textSign.setTypeface(textSign.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
```

I didn't try the `Spannable` option (which I assume MUST work) but

```
textSign.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.txt_sign)))
```

had no effect. Also if I remove the `italic tag` from `strings.xml` leaving the `setTypeface()` all alone it has no effect either. Tricky Android...

Answer (score 2):

In my case:

1 -  set text

2 - set typeface

```
holder.title.setText(item.nome);
holder.title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//leveraging the extension functions
fun TextView.makeBold(){
    this.setTypeface(this.typeface,Typeface.BOLD)
}


yourTextView.makeBold()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing that worked for me on a OnePlus 5T configured with the OnePlus Slate™ font:

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.create(textView.getTypeface(), useBold ? Typeface.BOLD : Typeface.NORMAL));
```

Other methods would make it fall back to Roboto when either BOLD or NORMAL.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to define it in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="common_txt_style_heading" parent="android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/common_txtsize_heading</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_black</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
</style>
```

And update it in `TextView`

```
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/txt_userprofile"
     style="@style/common_txt_style_heading"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
     android:text="@string/some_heading" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AppCompatTextView text =(AppCompatTextView)findViewById(R.layout.appCompatTextView1);
text.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
```

Use above method to set the typeface programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can set it with TypeFace.
2) You can directly use    ***in strings.xml(in your values folder)
3) You can String myNewString = " This is my bold text*** This is my italics string  This is my underlined string

Answer (score 0):

If you have another font variation settings and don't want to revert back to Roboto use this code:

```
val span = SpannableString(textView.text.toString())
span.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, span.length, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
textView.text = span
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have been looking for a solution myself and I didn't see what I came up with over here, I'll share:

You can use String resources

```
<resources>
    <string name="text">This text is <i>italic</i>. For bold use <b>this</b>. And you can underline with <u>this tag</u>.</string>
</resources>
```

Then you can directly link in your layout XML to this resource:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
```