# Android: Set text style to part of TextView text

Tags: android, textview

In Android, it is easy to [set a style for an entire TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200533/set-textview-style-bold-or-italic):

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
```

Is there a way to set a style for specific words (or characters) within the view? I would like to generate a line like:

> **Year**:2012, **Language**:Armenian, **Subtitles**:English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) to change style of specific word as:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + Year: + "</b>"+"2012,
                  "+"<b>" + Language: + "</b>"+":Armenian,"
                  "+"<b>" + Subtitles: + "</b>"+":English"));
```

**EDIT :**

if you have any issue to use `Html.fromHtml(...)` then you can go for [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) for Creating an String with different fonts,colors or style.

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(
    "<b> Year </b>2012<br> <b> Language </b>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you can use HTML format of text like below.

```
  textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Year:</b>2012,<b>Language</b>"));
```