# How do I set part of the description of a Radio button to be bold?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I am working on Android/Java. I want to set the description text of a Radio button in which the text is bit longer. It has two headings and one content field. I just want to make the headings bold and not the content. And I want the code in pure java

Comment: text of radio button should be bold..??

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469731) will help

Comment: yea. But not the whole text. Only heading part should be bold and content should be normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this line for radio button text

```
radioButtonObject.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Your heading</b>your contetn"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved my time and effort.