# Android, display formatted edittext in TextView

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set TextView style (bold or italic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200533/set-textview-style-bold-or-italic)

I am trying to implement an Evernote-like TextEditor in my application. Using this code I managed to make an EditText with options like bold, italic, color, size etc. 
[my link is here](http://code.google.com/p/android-richtexteditor/)

Once the content of the EditText is saved (it is saved in SqlLite), I should be able to view it, in a TextView. The problem is that I can see my content (saved from the EditText), but there is no formatting as specified (color, bold, italic).

Any suggestion on how to display this formatted text? Any tutorial that you know?

Comment: That content is saved as HTML or plain ?

Comment: The content is saved as plain, should I be saving it as HTML so that I can retain the formatting??

Comment: @Astor I am here trying to save the content in as formatted way and then display it TextView.Please let me know if I am not clear in my question

Comment: you should save content as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6200598/904049). And after this you won't have problem with displaying it.