# How to bold a text inside this AlertDialog?

Tags: android

There is an `AlertDialog` :

```
public class MessageDialogView extends AlertDialog {

    private View contenu, titleBar;

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    public MessageDialogView(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        super(context, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
        contenu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msg_dialog, null);
        titleBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_title, null);
        setCustomTitle(titleBar);
        setView(contenu, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, context.getResources().getString(R.string.button_ok), new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    public void setIcone(int resId) {
        ((ImageView)titleBar.findViewById(R.id.icone)).setImageResource(resId);
    }
    public void setTitre(String titre) {
        if (titre != null)
            ((TextView)titleBar.findViewById(R.id.titre)).setText(titre);
    }
    public void setMsg(String text){
        if (text != null)
            ((TextView)contenu.findViewById(R.id.msgText)).setText(text);
    }
}
```

Layout msg_dialog :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="@style/ImpotsStyle" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msgText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/ImpotsStyleTransparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="35dp"
            android:paddingBottom="35dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout custom_dialog_title :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ImpotsTitleStyle"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icone"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_warning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_alert_icone"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/titre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/ImpotsStyleText"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to show this `AlertDialog` inside an `activity` :

```
...
private MessageDialogView dlg = null;
private String champOblig = "";
...
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.parcelle);

        db = new Db(ParcelleActivity.this).open();

        afficherParcelle();

        dlg = new MessageDialogView(ParcelleActivity.this, getLayoutInflater());

    }
public void submit(View vue) { // onClick of a button

        if (chpObligVide()) {
            displaychpObligError();
            return;
        }
        ...
}
private boolean chpObligVide() {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(identification.getText().toString())) {
            champOblig = Formatage.bold(getResources().getString(R.string.identification)); // here I want to make the text to be bold
            return true;
        }
        champOblig = "";
        return false;
    }
    private void displaychpObligError() {
        dlg.setTitre(getResources().getString(R.string.titreErrMsgBox));
        dlg.setMsg(getResources().getString(R.string.chpOblig) + " " + champOblig);
        dlg.show();
    }
```

Class Formatage :

```
public class Formatage {

    public Formatage() {
        super();
    }
    public static String bold(String text) {

        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
        StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
        ssb.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        return ssb.toString();

    }

}
```

So how to make the text to be `bold` when shown inside the `AlertDialog` ?

Comment: have you tried the simple html bold tags inside a string?

Comment: I think it requires declaring a Spanned object , and I do not know how to work with them :)

Comment: Textview supports html `<b>bold</b>` tags. just try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  use `SpannableStringBuilder` you can't use `toString()` because otherwise you lost the bold formatting you just added.

Change your method bold to return `SpannedString`

```
public class Formatage {

    public Formatage() {
        super();
    }

    public static SpannedString bold(String text, String boldText) {
        int start = text.length() + 1;

        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text + " " + boldText);
        StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
        ssb.setSpan(boldSpan, start, start + boldText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        return new SpannedString(ssb);
    }
}
```

Now you need to change your activity method to support the new bold method:

```
private boolean chpObligVide() {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(identification.getText().toString())) {
        champOblig = getResources().getString(R.string.identification)); 
        return true;
    }
    champOblig = "";
    return false;
}

private void displaychpObligError() {
    dlg.setTitre(getResources().getString(R.string.titreErrMsgBox));
    dlg.setMsg(Formatage.bold(getResources().getString(R.string.chpOblig), champOblig));
    dlg.show();
}
```

In the end edit MessageDialogView to accept CharSequence instead String:

```
public void setMsg(CharSequence text) {
    if (text != null)
        ((TextView)contenu.findViewById(R.id.msgText)).setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can set 'Bold' style in the xml, or in the code.

[Set TextView style (bold or italic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200533/set-textview-style-bold-or-italic)

If you do in the code, I'll do like this,

```
public void setMsg(String text){
    if (text != null){
        TextView textView = ((TextView)contenu.findViewById(R.id.msgText));
        textView.setText(text);            
        textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
    }
}
```

In the xml,

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/msgText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ImpotsStyleTransparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingTop="35dp"
    android:paddingBottom="35dp" />
```

Comment: It is not the entire text that I want to bold , but the last part of it ! Look : `dlg.setMsg(getResources().getString(R.string.chpOblig) + " " + champOblig);`